# how to read line by line from file in bash script?

Tags: file, bash, scripting, line

I've searched online about this problem and I've found two ways so far:

```
   while read line; do
      commands
   done < "$filename"
```

and

```
    for $line in $(cat $filename); do
       commands
    done
```

none of these work if the lines have a space though, for example if we have a line like that

```
  textextext text
```

it won't print `textextext text`

but

```
  textextext
  text
```

it counts these things as a different line, how can I avoid this to happen?

Comment: Are you interested a) in leading and trailing whitespace or b) in intermediate whitespace (e.g. multiple spaces) or c) only in the words in one line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this?

```
while IFS= read line ; do
   something "$line"
done <"$file"
```

Here is a brief test:

```
while IFS= read line ; do echo "$line"; done <<<"$(echo -e "a b\nc d")"
a b
c d
```

Comment: isn't this the same thing I posted?

I think this won't work if the line has a space

Comment: empties input field separator. I've just updated post with the test I've just conducted.

Comment: thanks it worked great right now, I made a mistake on my first test

Comment: the other key diff is the addition of dbl-quotes around your ${line} variable. Good luck.

Comment: You're welcome. Double quotes wouldn't make it break lines, tho :)

Comment: You might want to add the -r option to read as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/10929955/770191

Comment: @AlbinoCordeiro, that's right, though, depends on how you want to handle escaped stuff.

Answer (score 7):

You can you readarray (bash 4+)

```
readarray lines < "$file"
```

then

```
for line in "${lines[@]}"; 
do
    echo "$line"
done
```

Note that by default `readarray` will even include the line-end character for each line

Comment: The "-t" arg to readarray will "remove a trailing newline from each line read."