# grep pattern and save to files with pattern name

Tags: grep

Trying to grep with patterns from one file and use them on a big one file and then save results to files with pattern name and grep output inside, does not work, empty files created.

What I am doing wrong?

```
while read p; do
grep $p big.txt >>$p
done < patterns.txt
```

Comment: What's the `patterns.txt` file like? In case it contains names with spaces, you can have problems.

Comment: the `-f` option read patterns from a file: `grep -f patterns.txt big.txt >>output` but if you need a different file foreach pattern, then you gave yourself already a solution, except that you have to be careful with what the read pattern contains (slashes, spaces, ...). Then, if a pattern gives no match, of course you will have empy files. Try the option `-c` to have a count of matches; if the files contains `0` (matches), then  it means your pattern doesn't match any line of the input.

Comment: patterns file contains simple word list , second level domain names, no slashes dots spaces and so on, words, words with hyphens. with -f tag empty files too.

Comment: Strange. What if you `grep something big.txt`? Try also to do `grep "$p" big.txt >> "$p"`, that is, to quote variables.

Comment: Thank you! >> "$p" did it :) (quotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in comments, you'd better quote the variables so that strange characters in the `patterns.txt` file will be treated as text:

```
while IFS= read -r p; do
  grep "$p" big.txt >> "$p"
done < patterns.txt
```

See [Read a file line by line assigning the value to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10929511/1983854) for an explanation on `IFS=` and `read -r`.