# reading cat file passing to command not working properly

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, cat

I have a file containing a list of process is input1  file

```
proc1
proc2 b
proc3 a
```

I use the following command to read the file and pass on the content of the file to a variable and then do something

```
for in in cat `input1`;do 
echo $i
done
```

It works fine for entries like proc1. But the problem is that it assigns only the proc2 to the variable $i and the also assign b to to $i etc etc ..  How can I pass the entire  proc2 b to variable $i   with the space in between ????

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/bash-scripting-read-file-line-by-line

Answer (score 0):

```
$ while IFS= read i; do echo $i; done <input1
proc1
proc2 b
proc3 a


$ IFS=$'\n'; for i in $(cat input1); do echo $i; done
proc1
proc2 b
proc3 a
```

**Update:** From the comments, it appears that you want to pass the name of a file from an outer loop to an inner loop which will read from the file.  In that case:

```
for fname in input1 input2
do
    while IFS= read i
    do 
        echo $i
    done <"$fname"
done
```

Or, if the file names are being read from a file called `filelist`:

```
while IFS= read fname
do 
    while IFS= read i
    do
        echo 1=$i
    done <"$fname"
done <filelist
```

Comment: Hi John .. I'm actually reading two files.. So I have a for I loop withing a for I loop ..  so I'm passing the name of the file from one for lopp to the next .. Not sure how I can use this command in my script

Comment: also I have the whole thing bundled  in  a sub shell in (

Comment: in short I cannot use the <input file command as u have stated

Comment: @theuniverseisflat See the update.  Also, to keep your question alive, you should update the question to talk about the loop-within-loop so that it is clear to whoever that your question is different from the claimed duplicate.

Comment: @theuniverseisflat Also, clarify where the subshell is being used.

Comment: I did try the second command u put and it works ... but not in my script - outside of the script it works fine. I'm passing the output as a variable and do a ssh and it gets all messed up thanks

Comment: @theuniverseisflat You need to update the question with the actual details of what you are doing rather than revealing it piece by piece.