# HBase - importing integers from a TSV file with ImportTsv tool?

Tags: csv, import, hbase, jruby, nosql

I would like to easily load data in my HBase table. I thought using the `ImportTsv` tool would be ideal. With something like this :

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv '-Dimporttsv.separator=;' -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,f:i tab import.tsv
```

I want values in the column "f:i" to be stored as **bytes (hex) NOT as strings**. Because direct consequence is that I am unable to query that column with filters needing to make integers comparisons.

*1 - If I use put in the shell :*

```
p = Put.new(Bytes.toBytes('r1'))
p.add(bytes('f'), Bytes.toBytes('i'), Bytes.toBytes(10));
tab.put(p)
```

*I get :*

```
r1  column=f:i, timestamp=1398519413393, value=\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0A
```

*2 - If I use the ImportTsv tool I get :*

```
r1  column=f:i, timestamp=1398519413393, value=10
```

But in this case my scans with the following filter (as an example) won't work anymore :

```
f = SingleColumnValueFilter.new(
  Bytes.toBytes('f'),
  Bytes.toBytes('i'),
  CompareFilter::CompareOp::LESS_OR_EQUAL,
  BinaryComparator.new(Bytes.toBytes(70))
)
```

So basically, is there a simple way to fine tune ImportTsv tool so that it stores the numbers like in the first case ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Tony, no luck.
Importtsv is wrong tool for binary data. Actually it is not good tool at all.

Looks like you need solution similar to what I do:

- MapReduce job which imports your data and outputs `HFile` image.
- `completebulkload` tool to bulk load prepared `HFile`.

Reference: https://hbase.apache.org/book/arch.bulk.load.html

More details:

- For importing MapReduce job you actually need only mapper. This mapper shall produce sequence of `Put` objects. Look for importtsv itself.
- Rest of importing job is just configured with things like `HFileOutputFormat2.configureIncrementalLoad(Job, HTable)`.
- I recommend to use HFileV2 due to number of reasons starting from luck of HFile V1 support in modern `HBase` clusters.
- `completebulkload` is just ready-to-use tool. I personally have my custom MapReduce job for this stage because I have native things like Snappy in my tables and don't want to install any native things on client. So I just start single mapper which takes HFile image from HDFS and merge with specified table.

Looks somewhat complex but indeed it worth to do yourself. Benefit is MUCH more efficient ETL operations.

Comment: Thanks Roman. I suppose you are right but I wished there was a much easier solution :-) Temporarily, I parse & import my data file with the Jruby interface. It's longer but easier to implement :-)

Comment: Depends on your requirements. I really need strong solution so I prefer to spend time but receive working thing. Currently I'm evaluating Spark for such class of tasks. Yet more complex but really powerful. BTW where is my +1 ;-) ?

Comment: Yet note: https://dataddict.wordpress.com/2013/03/08/some-upcoming-features-in-hbase-0-96/comment-page-1/ so please be careful. HBase 0.96 actually drops HFile V1 out of the market so I'd prefer standard solutions for bulk loading. V3 could be soon the only option.

Comment: We finally slightly modified the class 'TsvImporterMapper.java' to do what we need with integers. Indeed much much faster than using a layer of JRuby. You got your +1 ;-)

Comment: But please check you are using HFileV2 infrastructure. V1 is dying (for Cloudera, for example, is already dead).

Comment: ;) Looks like profit from this question will include yet +1.5 for 'answer' mark. Right now I'm investigating possibility to do what you are doing but based on Scala. Has sense because of Spark. So far so good but somewhat complex due to different language logic.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and ended up writing a small bash script to encode the hexadecimal characters of the tsv files.

*encode.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
# Transforms hexadecimal characters, e.g. \xFF to binary
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/bash-scripting-read-file-line-by-line
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo -e "$line"
done < "$1"
```

`./encode.sh $TABLE.tsv|hadoop fs -put - $HDFS_PATH/$TABLE.tsv`