# How to read each line of a file 1 at a time in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, file, shell, io

I need to read each line of a file in BASH one at a time and perform an operation on each line.

Here's some pseudo-code outlining what I need to have happen:

```
while( fileIsNotEmpty )
{
   line = ReadNextLine()

   SomeOperation(line)
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: There are *many* answers here providing solution to your question.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding them. Could you post a link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/bash-scripting-read-file-line-by-line

Comment: Thanks Sylvain. Sorry for the duplicate post!