# access to two or more file via read command on bash

Tags: bash, file

please look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/bash-scripting-read-file-line-by-line) to read from a file line by line,So I use the first answer and works:

First answer:

```
The following (save as rr.sh) reads a file from the command line:

#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    name=$line
    echo "Text read from file - $name"
done < $1
Run the script as follows:

chmod +x rr.sh
./rr.sh filename.txt
```

My question is If I want to read another file line by line , What I should do ? For example this code :

```
The following (save as rr.sh) reads a file from the command line:

#!/bin/bash
#this read refers to filename.txt
while read line 
do
    name=$line
    echo "Text read from file - $name"
done < $1
.
.
.
#this read refers to file2.txt
while read line 
do
    name=$line
    echo "Text read from file - $name"
done < $1
Run the script as follows:
```

How I can write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `$1` implies the name of the file to read from is passed as the first argument to your script. To read from two different files, pass both names as arguments:

```
rr.sh file1.txt file2.txt
```

and use `$2` for the input redirection to the second loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line 
do
    echo "Text read from file - $line"
done < "$1"

while read line 
do
    echo "Text read from file - $line"
done < "$2"
```

You can refer to as many command line arguments as you like. After the ninth argument (`$9`), you must use braces to enclose the number (so for the tenth, use `${10}`).

Answer (score 2):

what you need to do is to add a 'for' loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file; do
    while read line; do
        echo "Text read from $file - $line"
    done < "$file"
done
```

then run it as: ./rr.sh file1 file2 file3 otherfile*