# String concatenation doesn't work for comma character

Tags: bash, string-concatenation

String concatenation on bash script doesn't work on comma "," character.

```
A="Hello";
B=",World";
C=$A$B
echo $C;
```

It prints the output as

> Hello World

Bash version is:

```
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

The same code seems to work in [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php)

Comment: Cannot reproduce this on 3.1.20(4)-release or 4.2.25(1)-release...

Comment: `A="Hello";
B=",World";
C=$A$B
echo $C;` prints `Hello,World` just as it should.

Comment: Can't reproduce, guessing quoting both the assignment and use of `C` would stop it though.What happens if you just echo a comma ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **most likely explanation** is that you have **`$IFS` set to `,`**

The simplest way around this is to ***double-quote* `$C`**, in which case `echo` is passed the value *unmodified*:

```
echo "$C"
```

<sup>Also note that you don't need the semicolons to terminate your commands, given that each command is on its own line.</sup>

---

To **print the current value of `$IFS`** in unambiguous form, use

```
printf '%q\n' "$IFS"  # the default value will print as $' \t\n' - space, tab, newline
```

---

As for **why the `,` disappeared**:

- When you use an *unquoted* variable reference such as `$C`, the shell applies various [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) to the value.
- Notably, *word splitting* is applied, which means that the value is split into tokens using any of the characters contained in the special `$IFS` variable as a separator ("IFS" stands for "Internal Field Separator").
- By default, `$IFS` contains a space, a tab, and a newline, effectively splitting by *whitespace*.
- In your case, `$IFS` likely contained `,` resulting in `Hello,World` getting split into `Hello` and `World`, which are then passed to `echo` *as separate arguments*. As stated, double-quoting variable references prevents this behavior.
- `echo`, when given multiple arguments, *always* uses a *single space* to separate them on output.

---

**Tips for setting `$IFS`:**

Since **`$IFS` is a global variable**, it's **good practice to restore it to its previous value** after changing it:

```
prevIFS=$IFS IFS=',' # save old value, set desired value (',', in this example)
# ... perform operations with custom $IFS in effect
IFS=$prevIFS         # restore old value
```

However, there are **techniques that *localize* the change**, which means you do not have to explicitly save and restore its previous value:

---

If a custom `$IFS` value is only needed for a **single command based on an external utility or builtin** -- typically `read` -- **prepend `IFS=...` to the command**; e.g.:

```
IFS=/ read -r var1 var2 <<<'a/b'  # -> $var1 == 'a', $var2 == 'b'
```

This makes the changed `$IFS` take effect *only* for the command invoked.

**Caveat**: This does NOT work in situations where the changed IFS value must take effect BEFORE invoking the builtin / executable, such as with shell expansions; e.g.:

```
 # !! Does NOT work as intended, because $var is expanded BEFORE `IFS=/` takes effect.
var='a/b'; IFS=/ set -- $var
```

---

Inside a shell **function**, if you want to **change `$IFS` for the *entire* function, but *only* for that function**, **use a *local* `$IFS` variable** that *shadows* the global `$IFS`:

```
foo() {
    local IFS=/ var1 var2 # $IFS change confined to this function due to `local`
    read -r  var1 var2 <<<"$1"
    echo "[$var1] [$var2]"
 }

 foo "a/b" # -> '[a] [b]'
```

---

If feasible, **enclose a list of commands in a *subshell***:

```
(arr=(a b); IFS=/; echo "${arr[*]}") # -> 'a/b'
```

The `$IFS` modification is only visible to subshell.

**Caveat**: variables modified or created in the subshell are *not* visible to the current shell (which is, in fact, what this technique relies on).

Comment: Assuming that this solves the problem, nice job! I guess that the OP can just `echo "$IFS"` to find out whether it has been set to a comma (although I imagine that this wouldn't work so well for the default). Is there a good way to restore the default value?

Comment: @TomFenech: `IFS=$' \t\n'`

Comment: @TomFenech: Thanks, Tom. Good idea to print out the current value of `$IFS`; using `printf '%q\n' "$IFS"` instead of `echo` makes the control chars. visible.  In practice, _unsetting_ `IFS` makes it revert to its default behavior, though I wouldn't recommend it (it's not documented and other scripts may expect `$IFS` to return a value). Note that, by contrast, setting `IFS` to an _empty string_ effectively _disables_ word splitting.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @mklement0. It works, I reset the IFS value to its old state once am done with it

Comment: @RajkumarPalani: My pleasure; I've amended the answer with tips on how to manage `$IFS` changes.