# Append text at the beginning of lines in a file

Tags: bash, unix, random

I have a text file

**cat file.txt**

```
This is line1
This is line2
This is line3
This is line4.
```

My requirement is to append `Test1` ,`Test2` to the lines randomly.

Output should be as below.

```
Test1 This is line1
Test2 This is line2
Test1 This is line3
Test2 This is line4.
```

Comment: We are not here to do your job for you. You should make some attempts at solving the problem and then ask specific questions as to the problems you encounter.

Comment: You can see this question for better understanding: 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/bash-scripting-read-file-line-by-line)

Answer (score 2):

I would use `awk`:

```
awk '{r=int(rand()*2)+1; $0="Text"r" "$0}1' input
```

`int(rand()*2)+1` will return a random value between `1` and `2`. `$0="Text"r" "$0` adds `Text[Random]` at the start of each line. `1` is simply `true` and will lead to printing the modified line.

However this creates the same randomness across multiple invocations of it. Isn't this boring? If you want to have a different sequence of `1` and `2`s in every invocation you need to specify a *seed* for the random generator, like this:

```
awk -vseed="$RANDOM" 'BEGIN{srand(seed)}{r=int(rand()*2)+1; $0="Text"r" "$0;}1' input
```

`$RANDOM` is a special bash variable which contains a different random number each time you access it. Using `-v` you can pass variables from the command line to `awk`. The `awk` function `srand()` sets the seed for the random generator.

Answer (score 2):

A `bash` solution using `shuf`:

```
while read line;do 
 echo "Test$(shuf -i 1-2 -n 1) ${line}"
done<infile
```

Answer (score 1):

**addToLine.sh**

```
rand() {
    printf $((  $1 *  RANDOM  / 32767   ))
}
#rand_element borrowed from github.com/search?q=bashnative
rand_element () {
    local -a th=("$@")
    unset th[0]
    printf $'%s\n' "${th[$(($(rand "${#th[*]}")+1))]}"
}


sed -e 's/^/'"$(rand_element Test1 Test2)"' /' file.txt
```

---

**Output:**

```
Test1 This is line1
Test2 This is line2
Test1 This is line3
```

Learn more about [sed](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed)

Answer (score 1):

Based on hek2mgl's nice approach (+1 to him), let's first provide the set of words we want to add; then, use them randomly when printing:

```
awk -v text="Test1 Test2" '
       BEGIN {n=split(text, a)}
       {print a[int(rand()*n+1)], $0}' file
```

#### Test

```
$ awk -v text="Test1 Test2" 'BEGIN{n=split(text, a)} { print a[int(rand()*n+1)], $0}' a
Test1 This is line1
Test1 This is line2
Test2 This is line3
Test1 This is line4.
```

With more words:

```
$ awk -v text="Test1 Test2 Test3" 'BEGIN{n=split(text, a)} {print a[int(rand()*n+1)], $0}' a
Test1 This is line1
Test1 This is line2
Test3 This is line3
Test1 This is line4.
```

Comment: weirdly, it always prints 1 1 X 1, being X the number of elements

Comment: Also a nice idea! Likely even more useful than mine since usually random words will not end with a random number.

Answer (score 0):

Write a program in some language with a loop that:

- Writes `Test1` or `Test 2` to a file, with some kind of `random()`
  function
- Reads the next line (read all characters until the '\n' character)
- Write that line to the new file

Answer (score 0):

You could also do a loop:

```
while read i ; do
  echo $i | sed "s/^/Test$(( ( RANDOM % 2 ) + 1)) /"
done < file.txt
```