# Unix FOR loop not working with IP addressees

Tags: shell, loops, unix, for-loop

The below loop should read 1 line at a time to the veriable m. But it prints some junk value. Please help.

```
MyMachine:/u/home/Mohammed_Junaid> cat /tmp/F5
[10.222.73.99:22]
[10.000.73.99:22]
[10.111.73.99:22]
MyMachine:/u/home/Mohammed_Junaid> 
MyMachine:/u/home/Mohammed_Junaid> for m in $(cat /tmp/F5); do echo $m;done
1
2
1
2
1
2
MyMachine:/u/home/Mohammed_Junaid>
```

Comment: Which UNIX shell are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash Scripting & Read File line by line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/bash-scripting-read-file-line-by-line)

Answer (score 2):

Those strings are also valid glob-patterns. Because you're not quoting the `$m` variable, you're letting the shell perform [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion).

It happens that the string `[10.222.73.99:22]` is equivalent to the glob pattern `[012739.:]` which will match a filename of a single one of those characters, and it appears that you have a file named `1` and a file named `2` in your current directory.

[Always quote your shell variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells), and [don't use `for` to iterate the lines of a file](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

```
while IFS= read -r m; do echo "$m"; done < /tmp/F5
```