# Read line by line and print matches line by line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, text-processing

I am new to shell scripting, it would be great if I can get some help with the question below.

I want to read a text file line by line, and print all matched patterns in that line to a line in a new text file.

For example:

```
$ cat input.txt

SYSTEM ERROR: EU-1C0A  Report error -- SYSTEM ERROR: TM-0401 DEFAULT Test error
SYSTEM ERROR: MG-7688 DEFAULT error -- SYSTEM ERROR: DN-0A00 Error while getting object -- ERROR: DN-0A52 DEFAULT Error -- ERROR: MG-3218 error occured in HSSL
SYSTEM ERROR: DN-0A00 Error while getting object -- ERROR: DN-0A52 DEFAULT Error
SYSTEM ERROR: EU-1C0A  error Failed to fill in test report -- ERROR: MG-7688
```

The intended output is as follows:

```
$ cat output.txt

EU-1C0A TM-0401
MG-7688 DN-0A00 DN-0A52 MG-3218
DN-0A00 DN-0A52
EU-1C0A MG-7688
```

I tried the following code:

```bash
while read p; do
    grep -o '[A-Z]\{2\}-[A-Z0-9]\{4\}' | xargs
done < input.txt > output.txt
```

which produced this output:

```
EU-1C0A TM-0401 MG-7688 DN-0A00 DN-0A52 MG-3218 DN-0A00 DN-0A52 EU-1C0A MG-7688 .......
```

Then I also tried this:

```
while read p; do
    grep -o '[A-Z]\{2\}-[A-Z0-9]\{4\}' | xargs > output.txt
done < input.txt
```

But did not help :(

Maybe there is another way, I am open to awk/sed/cut or whatever... :)

**Note:** There can be any number of Error codes (i.e. XX:XXXX, the pattern of interest in a single line).

Comment: Any time you're considering using a shell loop to maniplulate text read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) to understand some, but not all, of the reasons not to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's always perl! And this will grab any number of matches per line.

```
perl -nle '@matches = /[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z0-9]{4}/g; print(join(" ", @matches)) if (scalar @matches);' output.txt
```

`-e` perl code to be run by compiler and 
`-n` run one line at a time and
`-l` automatically chomps the line and adds a newline to prints.

The regex implicitly matches against `$_`. So `@matches = $_ =~ //g` is overly verbose.

If there is no match, this will not print anything.

Answer (score 5):

```
% awk 'BEGIN{RS=": "};NR>1{printf "%s%s", $1, ($0~/\n/)?"\n":" "}' input.txt 
EU-1C0A TM-0401
MG-7688 DN-0A00 DN-0A52 MG-3218
DN-0A00 DN-0A52
EU-1C0A MG-7688
```

Explanation in longform:

```
awk '
    BEGIN{ RS=": " } # Set the record separator to colon-space
    NR>1 {           # Ignore the first record
        printf("%s%s", # Print two strings:
            $1,      # 1. first field of the record (`$1`)
            ($0~/\n/) ? "\n" : " ")
                     # Ternary expression, read as `if condition (thing
                     # between brackets), then thing after `?`, otherwise
                     # thing after `:`.
                     # So: If the record ($0) matches (`~`) newline (`\n`),
                     # then put a newline. Otherwise, put a space.
    }
' input.txt
```

Previous answer to the unmodified question:

```
% awk 'BEGIN{RS=": "};NR>1{printf "%s%s", $1, (NR%2==1)?"\n":" "}' input.txt 
EU-1C0A TM-0401
MG-7688 MG-3218
DN-0A00 DN-0A52
EU-1C0A MG-7688
```

*edit:* With safeguard against `:`-injection (thx @e0k). Tests that the first field after the record seperator looks like how we expect it to be.

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=": "};NR>1 && $1 ~ /^[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z0-9]{4}$/ {printf "%s%s", $1, ($0~/\n/)?"\n":" "}' input.txt
```

Comment: GNU `awk` accepts that as written; BSD (macOS) `awk` wants `(NR%2==1)` with the parentheses added (I'm not entirely sure why, but it yields a syntax error with the parentheses missing).  This then works with both.

Comment: Hi, joepd, I am interested in your awk solution.

Comment: However I might have any number of Error codes (I.e. XX-XXXX) in a line, will your suggestion still work in that case ?

Comment: This solution will only work for this exact format of output. If there were more error codes it wouldn't catch them.

Comment: Thanks Stats4224, I have edited my question with a note

Comment: Hi Joepd, would you be so kind to ellaborate on your last edit a bit more, I would like learn how it works :)

Comment: This solution exploits how each error code in the example is preceded by a `: `. If this string `: ` appears for any other reason, it would print something other than an error code (a false positive). There is no attempt to match the error code to a regular expression.

Comment: This will still only catch these error codes if they are of the format:
`<thing> : <code> <code> <thing>: <code> <code>`
but never:
`<thing>: <code> <code> <code> ` (the third code will be skipped). That said this has some really sweet awk nuggets of knowledge in it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler no, this will not work in BSD awk, it just appears to with a given sample input. The reason for that is the multi-char RS value is only supported by gawk. BSD awk will strip the blank char and just use `:`. That's fine if you really just want `:` to be the RS but wrong if you really want `:<blank>` as written.

Comment: @ joepd, the following command worked:

awk 'BEGIN{RS=": "};NR>1{printf "%s%s", $1, (NR%2==1)?"\n":" "}' input.txt

but as predicted by e0k this was not robust and resulted in other text also be printed which fir the ": " pattern

Then I tried your last solution with the built-in safeguard:

unfortunately this one did not extract any error codes at all :(, the command just ran successfully and no errors where printed, any idea ??

Comment: Ha, you might want to set `RS` to `ERROR: `. It seems like the error messages from your example always start with this. The command would become: `awk 'BEGIN{RS="ERROR: "};NR>1{printf "%s%s", $1, ($0~/\n/)?"\n":" "}' input.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You could always keep it extremely simple:

```
$ awk '{o=""; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="ERROR:") o=o$(i+1)" "; print o}' input.txt
EU-1C0A TM-0401
MG-7688 DN-0A00 DN-0A52 MG-3218
DN-0A00 DN-0A52
EU-1C0A MG-7688
```

The above will add a blank char to the end of each line, trivially avoided if you care...

Comment: Thanks Ed, its a simple and elegant solution, and fortunately in my case the error codes are always preceded with a "ERROR:"

Answer (score 1):

To keep your `grep` pattern, here's a way:

```
while IFS='' read -r p; do
    echo $(grep -o '[A-Z]\{2\}-[A-Z0-9]\{4\}' <<<"$p")
done < input.txt > output.txt
```

- `while IFS='' read -r p; do` is the standard way to read line-by-line into a variable.  See, e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10929511/2877364).
- `grep -o '[A-Z]\{2\}-[A-Z0-9]\{4\}' <<<"$p"` runs your grep and prints the matches.  The `<<<"$p"` is a ["here string"](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) that provides the string `$p` (the line that was read in) as `stdin` to `grep`.  This means `grep` will search the contents of `$p` and print each match on its own line.
- `echo $(grep ...)` converts the newlines in `grep`'s output to spaces, and adds a newline at the end.  Since this loop happens for each line, the result is to print each input line's matches on a single line of the output.
- `done < input.txt > output.txt` is correct: you are providing input to, and taking output from, the loop as a whole.  You don't need redirection within the loop.

Comment: @DineshKumar Sorry to hear that!  It worked on my cygwin installation.  What did it do when you tried?  This is definitely bash, not sh, which may make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that works if you know that every line will contain *exactly* two instances of the strings you want to match:

```
cat input.txt | grep -o '[A-Z]\{2\}-[A-Z0-9]\{4\}' | xargs -L2 > output.txt
```

Comment: See [UUoC — Useless Use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat/)

Comment: I have edited the question last Friday, see note in question

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with awk that is fairly straightforward, but it is not an elegant one-liner (as many awk solutions tend to be).  It should work with any number of your error codes per line, and with an error code defined as a field (white space separated word) that matches a given regex.  Since it's not a snazzy one-liner, I stored the program in a file:

**codes.awk**

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
    m=0;
    for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
        if ( $i ~ /^[A-Z][A-Z]-[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]$/ ) {
            if (m>0) printf OFS
            printf $i
            m++
        }
    }
    if (m>0) printf ORS
}
```

You would run this like

```
$ awk -f codes.awk input.txt
```

I hope you find it fairly easy to read.  It runs the block once for each line of input.  It iterates over each field and checks if it matches a regular expression, then prints the field if it does.  The variable `m` keeps track of the number of matched fields on the current line so far.  The purpose of this is to print the output field separator `OFS` (a space by default) between the matched fields *only as needed* and to use the output record separator `ORS` (a newline by default) only if there was at least one error code found.  This prevents unnecessary white space.

Notice that I have changed your regular expression from `[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z0-9]{4}` to `[A-Z][A-Z]-[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]`.  This is because old `awk` will not (or at least *may not*) support [interval expressions](https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html) (the `{n}` parts).  You could use `[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z0-9]{4}` with `gawk`, however.  You can tweak the regex as needed.  (In both awk and gawk, regular expressions are delimited by `/`.)

The regex `/[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z0-9]{4}/` would match any field that *contains* your XX-XXXX pattern of letters and digits.  You want the field to be a full match to the regex and not just *include* something that matches that pattern.  To do this, the `^` and `$` marks the beginning and end of the string.  For example, `/^[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z0-9]{4}$/` (with gawk) would match `US-BOTZ`, but not `USA-ROBOTS`.  Without the `^` and `$`, `USA-ROBOTS` *would* match because it includes a substring `SA-ROBO` that does match the regex.

Comment: Fortunately I have gawk, so I will try your idea too

Answer (score 1):

## Parsing `grep -n` with AWK

```
grep -n -o '[A-Z]\{2\}-[A-Z0-9]\{4\}' file | awk -F: -vi=0 '{
  printf("%s%s", i ? (i == $1 ? " " : "\n") : "", $2)
  i = $1
}'
```

The idea is to join the lines from the output of `grep -n`:

```
1:EU-1C0A
1:TM-0401
2:MG-7688
2:DN-0A00
2:DN-0A52
2:MG-3218
3:DN-0A00
3:DN-0A52
4:EU-1C0A
4:MG-7688
```

by the line numbers. AWK initializes the [field separator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Separators.html) (`-F:`) and the `i` variable (`-vi=0`), then processes the output of the `grep` command line by line.

It [prints](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf.html#Printf) a character depending on [conditional expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Conditional-Exp.html#Conditional-Exp) that tests the value of the first field `$1`. If `i` is zero (the first *iteration*), it prints only the second field `$2`. Otherwise, if the first field equals to `i`, it prints a space, else a newline (`"\n"`). After the space/newline the second field is printed.

After printing the next chunk, the value of the first field is stored into `i` for the next iterations (lines): `i = $1`.

## Perl

### Parsing `grep -n` in Perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $p = 0;

while (<>) {
  /^(\d+):(.*)$/;
  print $p == $1 ? " " : "\n" if $p;
  print $2;
  $p = $1;
}
```

Usage: `grep -n -o '[A-Z]\{2\}-[A-Z0-9]\{4\}' file | perl script.pl`.

### Single Line

But Perl is actually so flexible and powerful that you can solve the problem completely with a single line:

```
perl -lne 'print @_ if @_ = /([A-Z]{2}-[A-Z\d]{4})/g' < file
```

I've seen a similar solution in one of the answers here. Still I decided to post it as it is more compact.

One of the key ideas is using the `-l` switch that

1. automatically chomps the input record separator [`$/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$/);
2. assigns the output record separator [`$\`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$%5C) to have the value of `$/` (which is newline by default)

The value of output record separator, if defined, is printed after the last argument passed to `print`. As a result, the script prints all matches (`@_`, *in particular*) followed by a newline.

The `@_` variable is usually used as an array of subroutine parameters. I have used it in the script only for the sake of shortness.

Comment: This worked perfectly, only that I needed a small modification, to add the spaces
<br/>
perl -lne 'print(join(" ", @_)) if @_ = /([A-Z]{2}-[A-Z\d]{4})/g' < input.txt

the power of perl indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

In Gnu awk. Supports multiple matches on each record:

```
$ awk '
{
    while(match($0, /[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z0-9]{4}/)) {  # find first match on record
        b=b substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) OFS       # buffer the match
        $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)            # truncate from start of record
    }
    if(b!="") print b                           # print buffer if not empty
    b=""                                        # empty buffer
}' file
EU-1C0A TM-0401 
MG-7688 DN-0A00 DN-0A52 MG-3218 
DN-0A00 DN-0A52 
EU-1C0A MG-7688
```

Downside: there will be an extra OFS in the end of each printed record.

If you want to use other awks than Gnu awk, replace the regex `match` with:

```
while(match($0, /[A-Z][A-Z]-[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]/))
```

Comment: There's nothing gawk-specific about your script.

Comment: @EdMorton Well, apparently that regex works with Gnu awk but not with mawk or original-awk.

Comment: If by original awk you mean old, broken awk - no, nothing works with that. RE intervals are a POSIX feature though and so will work with any POSIX awk and most other modern awks.

Comment: I stand corrected. Unfortunately I only have access to abovementioned awks.