# Bash script to find largest file by parsing text tree

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, text

I need to write a script that look for the largest file in a given directory (including its subdirectories).

I figured out that If I use "tree" to generate a textual representation of all files, maybe then I can have the script to compare the sizes and output the largest one.

I ended up with a text file that looks something like this

```
.
[        939]  "./Documents/Alfa/driver/wlan0up"
[        234]  "./Documents/Alfa/driver/wpa1.conf"
[    1623520]  "./Documents/Alfa/driver/wpa_supplicant-0.5.5.zip"
[    5488640]  "./Documents/Alfa/R36-V1.2.1.2b6.img"
[       3385]  "./Documents/C code/Ide.s"
[       4096]  "./Documents/fluxion-master"
[         25]  "./Documents/fluxion-master/_config.yml"
[       4096]  "./Documents/fluxion-master/docs"
[      35141]  "./Documents/fluxion-master/docs/LICENSE"
[      83788]  "./Documents/fluxion-master/fluxion"
~~ long list of other files
[       6909]  "./.ZAP/session/untitled2.script"
[      64411]  "./.ZAP/zap.log"
[       4096]  "./.zenmap"
[          0]  "./.zenmap/recent_scans.txt"
[       2018]  "./.zenmap/scan_profile.usp"
[         85]  "./.zenmap/target_list.txt"
[       1486]  "./.zenmap/zenmap.conf"
[     409600]  "./.zenmap/zenmap.db"
[          5]  "./.zenmap/zenmap_version"

429 directories, 3327 files
```

Now, all I need is to have the script read through the list and compare the sizes until the list ends, then output the largest file's name and size.

I went through some other stackoverflow entries, using sed and grep, but didn't get any luck.

[Read a file line by line assigning the value to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable)

[Looping through the content of a file in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash)

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59417/extracting-data-from-text-file-in-bash-using-awk-grep-head-and-tail

Please note that tree is capable of formatting the output as xml file, using tags and attributes like `<directory name="fileName" size="XXXX"></directory>`
so if parsing the xml file is easier, that would be fine too.

folders are also listed in there, but we can ignore that.

Any help would be appreciated, 
Thanks

Comment: elaborate your question: to find *the largest file* by file size OR by number of lines within a file ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant by size, the number between brackets was in bytes.. anyway the solution was really simple.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sort your list by the numbers and grab the first line:

```
sort -V yourList.txt | head -n
```

I have the feeling that you have a rather large script to produce the list. The list is also a bit unsafe. What happens if a filename contains a newline (yes, that is possible on linux)? The following command finds the largest file and in the current directory (including subdirectories) and prints its size and name.

```
find . -type f -exec du -b {} + | sort -nr | head -n 1
```

if you want just the file, add `| sed 's/^[0-9]\+\t//'` to the end.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `tree`. Instead, just iterate over the files and call `stat` to get the size of each file, remembering the largest file seen so far. In `bash` 4 or later, it is as simple as

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*; do
    size=$(stat -c %s)
    if (( size > max_size )); then
        max_size=$size
        max_file=$f
    fi
done
```

If you have `zsh` available, it is as simple as `fname=$(zsh -c 'print **/*(OL[1])')`.

With earlier version of `bash`, you need to define a recursive function to simulate `**`:

```
dir_iter () {
    for f in "$1"/*; do
        if [[ -d $f ]]; then
            dir_iter "$f"
        else
            size=$(stat -c %s)
            if ((size > max_size)); then
                max_size=$size
                max_file=$f
            fi
        fi
    done
}
dir_iter .
```

(Note that you should consult your local documentation for the exact form of the `stat` command, which may vary. BSD `stat`, for instance, uses `-f` instead of `-c`.)

---

One objection is that it requires multiple calls to `stat`. This is expensive, but avoids the (admittedly rare) issue
of dealing with sequences of files names (which is complicated when file names can contain newlines).

If you have `zsh` available, it is as simple as `max_file=$(zsh -c 'print **/*(OL[1])')`. If you are actually *using* `zsh`, then it's just `print -v max_file **/*(OL[1])`.

If you decide to not worry about filenames with newlines, you can do the following:

```
find . -exec stat -c '%s %n' {} + | sort -k2,2nr | head -1
```

---

I leave dealing with filenames containing newlines as an exercise to the reader; typically, I would just use a different language that can represent sequences of arbitrary strings properly. Another option would be to look at the `finfo` command found in the `examples/loadables` directory of the `bash` source distribution. It's an example of creating a shell built-in command that does the same thing as `stat` without creating a new process. It could be modified to add a `-v` option similar to that supported by `printf` so that you can set a shell variable from the output.

```
finfo -v size -s "$f"  # equivalent to size=$(stat -c %s "$f"), but all in shell
```