# Creating users from .txt file

Tags: bash, awk

I'm given the following ".txt" file, containing a list of usernames:

```
user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, user6, user6, user7, user8, user9, user10
```

From the following, I have to create different users, using each value as the username and same value for the password.

I've tried to, from that list, create a new one writing the usernames in columns, and then create the users from that new .txt file.

```
IFS=$'\n'

lst1=$(cat /path/of/file/a.txt)

for i in $lst1
do
   a1=$(echo $i |awk '{print $1}')
   useradd $a1 
  a2=$(echo $i | awk'{print $1}')   echo-e "$a2\n$a2" | passwd $a1   
done
```

But it's not working at all..., I can't take the comma out from the string, and it doesn't allow me to create the user.

Anyone could advice me on how to do it properly?

Comment: You may want to read [Read a file line by line assigning the value to a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10929511/1983854)

Comment: That's a very poor design for the input.  Use either comma delimited or whitespace delimited, or perhaps go for newline-delimited.

Comment: Also, your quoting is hosed.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable

Comment: `for i in $(tr -d ',' </path/of/file/a.txt)`