# Can I script a program to run repeatedly with arguments from a text file?

Tags: bash, parsing, file-io, terminal

My question is: I have a program written in C and to launch it I'm used to do

```
./program.exe var_1 ... var_n
```

where var_i-th are both numeric values and strings (used as filenames).
I have to make the program run many times with different values of var_i-th and each time I have to call the above command.

Is there a way to prepare a file .txt (or something similar) of the kind

- ./program.exe var_1 ... var_n  #configuration one
- .
- .
- ./program.exe var_1 ... var_n #configuration N

and to make the program run using this so that in a single call I get all the configurations run one by one?

Thanks

Comment: Shell scripts will execute each line as though you had typed it in a console (more or less).  So you should be able to just write all the commands in a file, then execute that--or are you looking for a way to have the script generate all the configuration permutations or something like that?

Comment: Not a C issue, therefore remove the C tag.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/10929453/694576

Comment: Do you have a file containing all the parameters you need to run the program with? Or can they be generated easily - e.g. 1..100?

Comment: Keep in mind that the signature for the entry point to a C program is `int main(int argc, char** argv)`, so *all* your arguments are passed as C strings, no matter whether they're intended to be parsed to numbers or not.

Comment: The important question we need answered is whether your arguments need to be able to contain whitespace, and thus, whether quoting or escaping needs to be honored. If there's other content that needs expansion -- wildcards, for instance -- that needs to be covered as well.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, I know. I was meaning the line would be someting like
./program.exe 1 2 3 file_one.dat file_two.dat file_three.dat
Thanks however

Comment: The question I asked above -- which you haven't at yet answered -- is whether we only need to care about `file_one.dat` or also about `"file one.dat"`.

Comment: You need to care just about file_one.dat and not on "file_one.dat"
However, the answer by Cyrus is working very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a text file (`foo.sh`, e.g.) with this content, make it executable (`chmod u+x foo.sh`) and run it with `./foo.sh`:

```
#/bin/bash

/program.exe var_1 ... var_1 #configuration one
/program.exe var_1 ... var_2 #configuration two
/program.exe var_1 ... var_3 #configuration three
.
.
.
./program.exe var_1 ... var_n #configuration N
```

Answer (score 3):

To read each line into an array of strings, and pass that array to a program being run, can use methods described in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001):

```
while read -r -a args; do
  ./program.exe "${args[@]}"
done <in.txt
```

will read arguments from `in.txt`, expecting them to be whitespace-separated. It *will not* honor quotes or escape sequences as syntactically meaningful.

---

The caveat is that if your file contains:

```
arg1 "argument two" 13
```

you'll get:

```
./program.exe 'arg1' '"argument' 'two"' '13'
```

...for a total of *four* arguments.

---

If you need quotes to be honored, then we're back in the space of using `xargs`, but with one invocation per input line:

```
while read -r line; do
  xargs ./program.exe <<<"$line"
done <in.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You may prepare a file with a customized parameter list per line, like this:

```
var_1
var_2
var_1 var_3
```

Then a bash sentence like this would do the work:

```
cat myFile.txt | xargs ./program.exe
```

Comment: I suggest: `xargs -n 1 ./program.exe <myFile.txt`

Comment: The approach suggested in this answer won't do what the OP asks -- it would invoke `./program.exe var_1 var_2 var_1 var_3` with your input file, treating spaces and newlines identically. (I'd also suggest ditching `cat`, as `xargs ./program.exe <myFile.txt` or `<myFile.txt xargs ./program.exe` will give `xargs` a direct handle on the input file which it can read from more efficiently than going through a FIFO).

Comment: @Cyrus, ...the OP wants to be able to pass more than one argument per invocation, so that's not quite right either.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Thank you. What about `xargs -n 1 -d '\n' ./program.exe <myFile.txt`?

Comment: @Cyrus, that would be passing `var1 var_3` as a single argument in the 3rd-line example, rather than as two.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Okay, it was an attempt.