# Bash - Concatenate line with the one below

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cat

I need to concatenate a text file with a couple of lines. This one is my situation:

```
USER abc  
PASS 123  
USER efg  
PASS 456   
USER hil  
PASS 789
```

and so on...

I need an output like this:

```
USER abc PASS 123  
USER efg PASS 456     
USER hil PASS 789
```

I tried solutions like:

```
awk 'NR % 2 == 1 { o=$0 ; next } { print o "<sep>" $0 } END { if ( NR % 2 == 1 ) { print o } }' INPUTFILE

sed -rn 'N;s/\n/ /;p' yourFile

cat file | paste -d' ' - -
```

What I recieved as output was:

```
USER abc  
_PASS 123  
USER efg  
_PASS 456
```

Where `_` is a simple space.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable this is how to read line into var, no write every two vars out to different file's one line

Comment: i can solve the problem doing 2 tmp file just with a grep and then make a paste command from the 2 files. but i'm trying a simple solution

Comment: for me  tmp would seem as simple solution, but good solution would be in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cat file | paste -d' ' - -` should work:

```
$ cat /tmp/t.txt
USER abc
PASS 123
USER efg
PASS 456
USER hil
PASS 789
$ cat /tmp/t.txt | paste -d' '  - -
USER abc PASS 123
USER efg PASS 456
USER hil PASS 789
```

If it does not, try running `dos2unix` on your file to make sure it has proper line endings.

Comment: many thanks, i thoung there was some problem with line endings so i was trying a tr, untill i saw your comment. many thanks! it wokrs|

Comment: UUOC. `paste -d' ' - - < file`

Answer (score 0):

Easy with sed:

```
sed 'N;s/\n/ /' file
```

`N` appends the next line to the pattern space, and `s/\n/ /` replaces the newline character with a space.

Note that if the newline sequence is different, you have to change `\n` to the correct sequence: `\r\n` for Windows files, `\r` for old Mac file format...

Answer (score 0):

with paste:

```
paste -sd' \n \n' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, (NR%2 ? OFS : ORS)}' file
USER abc PASS 123
USER efg PASS 456
USER hil PASS 789

$ awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, (NR%3 ? OFS : ORS)}' file
USER abc PASS 123 USER efg
PASS 456 USER hil PASS 789

$ awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, (NR%6 ? OFS : ORS)}' file
USER abc PASS 123 USER efg PASS 456 USER hil PASS 789
```

Notice how you simply change the number from "2" to whatever you like to print however many lines you want concatenated? Try that with any other posted solution.