# Parse text file, find matching lines and save to text file

Tags: bash

How would I write a bash script that parses a text file, finding any lines that contain the word `command:` and then saves the entirety of each line on which it was found on to a text file?

Answer (score 3):

The command would be

```
grep command: your_filename >> save_filename
```

Which is

```
#!/bin/bash
grep command: $1 >> $2
```

Executed by

```
scriptname your_filename save_filename
```

Thanks David

Note that I'm using an appender >>, instead of a create >.  The latter ensures a file with only your last run in it, whereas the appender will add new lines to the file if it already exists.

Comment: Or run `grep` in a subshell and redirect (truncate/write) once, e.g. (`grep command: your_filename) > save_filename`. Either way is fine, but you may want an `:>your_filename` before the `grep` call to insure `your_filename` is empty to begin with using the `>>` append redirection.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a **pure `bash`** solution of this **`grep`-like behaviour**:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: ./mygrep ERE_PATTERN FILENAME
while IFS= read -r line || [[ $line ]]; do
    [[ $line =~ $1 ]] && echo "$line"
done <"$2"
```

(We iterate over lines of the file given in the second positional parameter, `$2`, in a [pretty standard way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10929511/404556), checking for a match with a pattern given as the first parameter inside a [conditional expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b) with the `=~` operator, printing all lines that match.)

Invoke it like:

```
./mygrep command: file
```

Although *much* slower than `grep`, one nice thing about this script is that it supports **POSIX ERE** (extended regular expressions) **by default** (you don't need to specify `-E` like you do in `grep`), e.g.:

```
./mygrep 'com.*:' file
./mygrep '^[[:digit:]]{3}' file
# etc
```