# Bash _ wget _html2txt

Tags: bash, wget

I was asked to use `wget` to download multiple url saved in a file and stock them in another folder. so I used this command:

`wget -E -i url.txt -P ~/Desktop/ProjectM2/data/crawl`

but ***Prob number 1*** the files have to be named as follow:

```
1.html
2.html
3.html
..
```

and I tried manny things and I still can't do it.

***Prob number 2*** 
I don't know how to change all these files in one command using `html2txt -utf8` from  `.html` to `.txt` and keeping also the numbers

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
..
```

thank you

Comment: What do you mean under `I tried manny things`? What did you try exactly? Can you show an example what urls are in url.txt?

Comment: I tried to use the for in  do

Comment: url like http://www.lefigaro.fr/culture/2010/12/31/03004-20101231ARTFIG00461-le-bonheur-est-dans-la-cuisine.php

https://www.universalis.fr/encyclopedie/egypte-antique-histoire-l-egypte-pharaonique/

Comment: How did you try the `foor loop`? Is the order of urls in url.txt important for the new names? I mean 1.html should be the first in url.txt, 2.html the second ... and so on? The resulting filenames from your wget command would be unpredictable like this, if the order is important you should go through the url.txt file line by line

Comment: can you explain more please ? how can I go from line to another ?

Answer (score 0):

If in your case the order of urls in `url.txt` is important, that is, `1.html` should contain the data of the first url, then `2.html` should corresponds to the second url and so on then you can process the urls one by one.

The following script takes the desired action for each url:

```
#!/bin/bash

infile="$1"

dest_dir="~/Desktop/ProjectM2/data/crawl"

# create html and txt dir inside dest_dir
mkdir -p "$dest_dir"/{html,txt}

c=1
while IFS='' read -r url || [[ -n "$url" ]]; do

    echo "Fetch $url into $c.html"
    wget -q -O "$dest_dir"/html/$c.html "$url"

    echo "Convert $c.html to $c.txt"
    html2text -o "$dest_dir"/txt/$c.txt "$dest_dir"/html/$c.html

    c=$(( c + 1 ))

done < "$infile"
```

The script accounts for an input file, in this case `url.txt`. It creates two directories (`html`, `txt`) under your destination directory `~/Desktop/ProjectM2/data/crawl` in order to better organize the resulting files. We read the urls from the file `url.txt` line by line with the help of a while loop ([Read file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable)). With `wget` you can specify the desired output filename with the `-O` option, thus you can name your file as you wish, in your case a sequence number. The `-q` option is used to remove wget messages from the command line. In `html2text` you can specify the outputfile using `-o`.

Comment: I can't understand where did you put the path of the folder url.txt ?

Comment: You have to save the code from above into a file, for example: fetch.sh. Then make it executable. Then you can run the script: ./fetch.sh path/to/url.txt. The infile=“$1” expression in the code do the magic. That is, take the first argument of the call and use it as infile variable.

Comment: I tried your script but I found a lot of errors so I tried this 

#!/bin/bash 
c=1
while read line; do


    wget -q -i ~/Bureau/ProjetM2_DreemAT/data/input/url.txt   -O  ~/Bureau/ProjetM2_DreemAT/data/crawl/$c.html 

    html2text -o ~/Bureau/ProjetM2_DreemAT/data/crawl/$c.html    ~/Bureau/ProjetM2_DreemAT/data/txt/$c.txt  

    c=$(( c + 1 ));

done < ~/Bureau/ProjetM2_DreemAT/data/input/url.txt                                                 so some files were created 1.html 2.html but with nothing inside plus 1.txt files were not created

Comment: I posted my answer because it is tested and works. What was the lot of error you found?

Comment: Also it is wrong what you mentioned in your comment. You use the `-i` flag with input list in `wget` and you also iterate through this file..