# Shell: move files one by one an other directory

Tags: shell, move

I have 2 directory. `doc1` and `doc2` and I have a lot of files in the directory of `doc1`.

In the directory `doc1`, I have the files as:

```
cp01_01
cp02_01
cp03_01
cp04_01
...
```

I want move these files **one by one** from `doc1` to `doc2`, in order to execute other commands between each `mv`. How can I do that?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to do this one by one? Do you want to do some other actions before actually moving the file?

Comment: Hi maybe it will help to you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable

Comment: Hi in this link, script read .txt file line by line, I want move files one by one ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for` to loop over your file:

```
for file in doc1/cp*_* ; do
    mv "$file" "doc2/$(basename "$file")"
    echo "$file moved! Executing some other stuff..."
    # some other stuff
done
```

Comment: After looking again I saw the script run. Thanks all