# How to read a file line by line into a variable without a loop

Tags: bash, file, loops, xargs, gnu-parallel

So you know this right?:
[Read a file line by line assigning the value to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable)

How do you do this without a loop, I'm in a situation where loops would case errors and a mess.(If you've ever tried messing with parallel) But I still need to read a file line by line.

Is there some way of doing it without a loop? `xargs`? `awk`? `parallel`?

Comment: You can't read line by line without a loop. It's not possible. Even if you read the entire file into memory all at once, to process it line by line you need a loop. Your question makes no sense. And if your code is so poorly written that a loop would *cause errors and a mess*, fix your code first and then add the loop.

Comment: You can use `readarray` to read a file into an array.

Comment: Remember to ask questions in such a way that the answer will be useful to you. You can totally do `parallel 'var={}; echo "$var"' < file` which fits the question exactly, but it may be slow, inapplicable or stupid for a real world script

Comment: @thatotherguy Upvote for getting quoting of " space and \n correct.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`readarray`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) to read the whole file into an array variable. Each line will be an array element.

```
readarray -t arrayname < filename
```

Comment: It's synonym `mapfile` may also add to its use here. It was always a bit puzzling the lack of distinction between the two. The only discernible difference I could see was that `mapfile` would use the environment variable `MAPFILE` as the array.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Does it even have that difference? The `readfile` documentation says the variable is optional, so I assume it defaults the same. The documentation implies that `mapfile` is the preferred name, but I usually see people using `readarray` (the name seems more intuitive).

Answer (score 1):

The question really doesn't make much sense to me, but you can certainly do:

```
{
read line_one <&3; # Read from the input file
echo "The first line is $line_one"
read line_two -u 3;  # A different method to read
echo "The second line in $line_two"
...
} 3< input file
```

Note that it's not really necessary to read from fd 3, but it's much safer if your commands are not reading from the same input as the reads.

But if you're truly "in a situation where loops would case errors and a mess" then you have a problem for which this is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, using a recursive function (well, recursion might be a loop...). First some test material:

```
$ seq 1 4 > file
```

then the function `fun`:

```
$ fun() {
    if read -r line <&5      # read from defined FD 5
    then 
        echo process $line   # process the lines here
        fun                  # recursive function call
    fi
}
```

calling for `fun`:

```
$ exec 5< file
$ fun
process 1
process 2
process 3
process 4
$ exec 5<&-                  # close the FD
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear what you are asking. Maybe you are simply asking for:

```
myvar="$(cat thefile)"
```