# passing same command with different parameter multiple time (from linux command prompt) and saving result in a single file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a `.txt` file which contains different words ( 1 million words ). I want to make a single output file containing information about the occurrences of words. I am using the command:

```
$ ./dumpindex /home/pankaj/indri-5.0/Query/indri_test_may.idx/ t "input_word_from_file" > /home/pankaj/output_file.txt
```

`input_word_from_file` is the query word from the file.

Issues:

1. How to pass the input word automatically to the command from the file
2. How to write the output file in append mode. ( because it gets updated with the latest output of the run command).

Comment: append is >> instead of >

Comment: Thanks Drako. Any suggestions for issue (1).

Comment: I agree that this should be deleted as duplicate - was just quicker to answer then search for obviously existing duplicate :D or change to have 1 question only

Comment: you have to read(google read file bash and find some tutorial on bash basics - my suggestion) that word from file and then use << to pass as input for command

Comment: @Drako can you please specify the command syntax. Thanks

Comment: this line by line - split in words if necessary 9- also just do for your own good - google bash tutorial and go quickly through basics - it will make your life easier :) ) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for append use >> instead of >

```
$ ./dumpindex /home/pankaj/indri-5.0/Query/indri_test_may.idx/ t "input_word_from_file" >> /home/pankaj/output_file.txt
```