# How to match file extension in bash?

Tags: string, bash, shell, string-matching

I want to call a function ONLY when the file name ends with `.request` but somehow it calls the function if `request` is **sub-string**.

I [marked with red and green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20ASq.png) the imported parts, on the right it's the output

```
for file in ${filesOrDir[*]}; do    
    if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
        if [[ "$file"=*[".request"] ]]; then
            # Enters here when .request is a substring.
        fi
    fi
    if [[ -d "$file" ]]; then
            # ... some logics       
    fi
done
```

Comment: in picture there's screenshot

Comment: provide the code

Comment: `[[ $file = *.request ]]` ?

Comment: is it better or should I put the whole script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use: `[[ $file == *.request ]]`

`handle-request.sh` is a helping script for checking file names.

**handle-request.sh:**

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    if [[ $line == *.request ]]; then
        echo $line
    fi
done < "$1"
```

**Explanation:** [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10929511/7882470)

`IFS=''` (or IFS=) prevents leading/trailing whitespace from being trimmed.

`-r` prevents backslash escapes from being interpreted.

`|| [[ -n $line ]]` prevents the last line from being ignored if it doesn't end with a `\n` (since  read returns a non-zero exit code when it encounters `EOF`).

**input** file:

```
hello.request
.request.hello
file name with space.request
```

**Output:**

```
hello.request
file name with space.request
```

Comment: good luck with matam

Comment: thanks, it's my second time... the question is if the code above works also if I have spaces in the file name?

Comment: I added addition input with spaces

Comment: Select the `V` under the answer votes so it turns green