# Parse specific string my matching pattern from a input text file in bash

Tags: bash, awk, pattern-matching, filereader, extract-value

I am passing a text file as a command line input to a script and need to parse through the file searching for a specific pattern:

```
00 TOOL     | Running /variable/directory/path/to/the/tool/executable in batch (pid xxxxx)
```

Now I have to extract `/variable/directory/path/to/the/tool/executable` to a variable say `$executable`.

Here, the portion which remains constant is `00 TOOL     | Running` at the starting of a line and `in batch (pid xxxxx)` at the ending of a line where `xxxxx` is again a variable.

Provided that in the input text file, this line will appear only once.

I have found out the [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable) to read line by line, but can not find out a way to read the above said variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo "Text read from file: $line"
done < "$1"
```

Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: `awk '{print $5}' file`?

Comment: @Cyrus there are several other lines also. By using `awk` like this all the lines will get selected without pattern match!

Comment: @RandomCoder yes and that would still be orders of magnitude faster than a shell loop alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case your path's value is not a set field and you want to match it as regex form then try following once.

```
val=$(awk 'match($0,/\/[^ ]*/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);exit}' Input_file)
```

You could set its value to a variable by doing `var=$(awk code above)`

Comment: I need only the first line of the output. I tried `var=$(awk 'match($0,/\/[^ ]*/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file | head -n 1)`. As the `Input_file` is of big size, its taking loads of time to get output! Any alternative suggestion would be helpful!.

Comment: @RandomCoder, if you need only very first match then could you please try my edited solution and let me know if that helps you?

Comment: Yes. I only need the first match!

Comment: @RandomCoder, then please try my edited one it shouldn't not take that much time also since it will exit after first match, let me know how it goes then?