# Read lines from a file enclosed matching pattern of starting line and ending line and append it to another text file in bash

Tags: bash, awk, append, pattern-matching, readfile

I have to read specific lines form a input file received in command line and alter all the lines and append it into another text file.

The input file has these lines(*this set of lines apears only once*):

```
00 TOOL     | Value of SIMIN:
00 TOOL     |   /absolute/path/to/some/required/file_1
00 TOOL     |   /absolute/path/to/some/required/file_2
00 TOOL     |   /absolute/path/to/some/required/file_3
00 TOOL     |   
00 TOOL     | Value of SIMOUT:
```

Lines we need to read are in-between two specific patterned.

Starting pattern:

```
00 TOOL     | Value of SIMIN:
```

Ending pattern:

```
00 TOOL     |   
00 TOOL     | Value of SIMOUT:
```

Later I need to convert it to following lines and append it to another file:

```
export SIMIN=/absolute/path/to/some/required/file_1:$SIMIN
export SIMIN=/absolute/path/to/some/required/file_2:$SIMIN
export SIMIN=/absolute/path/to/some/required/file_3:$SIMIN
```

Got to know from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable) how to read a file line by line.

But in my requirement, I may need to read the file in a buffer at a time, search for the above said line patterns and pick up the middle lines and alter them.

Any help/suggestion will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
/SIMOUT/{
  flag=""
}
/SIMIN/{
  flag=1
}
flag && match($0,/\/[^ ]*/){
  print "export SIMIN=" substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)":$SIMIN"
}
'  Input_file
```

In case you want to take its output into a output file append `> output_file` to above code.

***EDIT:*** Adding solution from ED sir too here.

```
awk '/SIMOUT/{f=0} f&&/\//{printf "export SIMIN=%s\n", $NF} /SIMIN/{f=1}' Input_file
```

Comment: The `flag` test block should come between the 2 SIM test blocks since you don't want to call match() for the SIMIN line. You also don't need match() or substr(): `awk '/SIMOUT/{f=0} f&&/\//{printf "export SIMIN=%s\n", $NF} /SIMIN/{f=1}' file`.

Comment: @EdMorton, sure sir added it now, thank you for letting me know.