# Shell Scipt only runs through single iteration of certificate for 100 sites where it should run 100 times

Tags: shell, ssl-certificate

Script:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do

    echo "Line is : $line"


    openssl s_client -showcerts -connect "$line:443" | grep Certificate

done < top100.csv
```

The top100.csv file contains the URL's for the top 100 websites for the script to run through. However, the script is only outputting the certificate for the first website, this being google.com. I need it to keep looping through the rest of the lines of the file.

I apologize in advance for any wording errors or misspelling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read a file line by line assigning the value to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable)

Comment: I don't believe so. That post has more to do with parsing the file and EOF.

Comment: What is your top100.csv content