# How to modify multiple files using a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting

I have a file called `script.sh` with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=list.txt
IFS=$','
cat $file 
for i in `cat $file`
do
    echo "The name of the file I am going edit is $i"
    awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} /^\<AA_xx\>/||/^\<AA\>/{$160="CC,0,DD,0"} 1' $i \
        > temp_file.csv && mv temp_file.csv $i
done
```

`list.txt` contains the path to a `.csv` file, e.g., `/ws/user/stack.csv`.

However, I would like to modify this script to read all the files I specify in `list.txt`, i.e., my `list.txt` contains

```
/ws/user/stack.csv
/ws/user/stack1.csv
/ws/user/stack2.csv
```

I want the script to use this awk in each file mentioned in `list.txt`.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: What are you saying is the issue here? Are you saying lilst.txt isn't being read properly? I you set `IFS=","`. Are the filenames in list.txt comma separated or newline separated? If newline separated, checkout out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable

Comment: It is newline separated

Answer (score 0):

The following does the trick

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    cat "$line" | awk '{print $0}' > "output_$line"
done < "$1"
```

Then you just call it with

```
$ ./script.sh list.txt
```

If you have a large awk code, I recommend organizing it in a function.

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
yourAwkFunction(){
    awk '{print $0}'
}

while read -r line; do
    cat "$line" | yourAwkFunction > "output_$line"
done < "$1"
```

`line` is the variable that receives the value of each line of `list.txt`. This means that `line` is `/ws/user/stack.csv` for the first iteration and then `/ws/user/stack.csv1` for the second and so on.

For more on reading lines of files, you may check http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Does this take care of new line separation of each file? I donot need IFS right?

Comment: I've tested with a list.txt in which each line corresponds to a file name and it worked. If you have a newline separated list.txt, you don't need to specify IFS

Comment: what is line in this case and $line?

Comment: I've clarified in the answer

Comment: how do I modify my awk function here? $i \
        > temp_file.csv && mv temp_file.csv $i What is $i in this case then?

Comment: I've changed the code. Just copy and past and it will do what you want

Answer (score 0):

Since your comment says list.txt is newline separated, just follow how to read a file line by line here:  [Read a file line by line assigning the value to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable)

Which would give you:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r file || [[ -n "$file" ]]; do
  echo "The name of the file I am going edit is $file"
  awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} /^\<AA_xx\>/||/^\<AA\>/{$160="CC,0,DD,0"} 1' $file \
    > temp_file.csv && mv temp_file.csv $file
done < list.txt
```

Comment: How do I run the script? just ./script.sh?

Comment: Exactly. Here, I just hardcoded list.txt as input. You can also use `"$1"` in place of list.txt above and run with `./script.sh list.txt`

Comment: The name of the file I am going edit is /ws/user/stack.csv
The name of the file I am going edit is /ws/user/stack1.csv
The name of the file I am going edit is
mv: missing destination file operand after `temp_file.csv'
Try `mv --help' for more information.

Comment: The third line the name of the file I am going to edit is is empty.. and then it says missing destination file from operand

Comment: This is because it is trying to mv temp.csv to /ws/user/stack.csv .. which is an invalid location. How do I go to one directory above

Comment: How is /ws/user/stack.csv an invalid location? Either way, if you want to go one directory use `..`. So saying `/ws/user/../` would be the directory `/ws/user/`.