# Read a file line-by-line on bash; each line containing the path to another unqiue file

Tags: bash, shell, vim

Each line in a given file '*a.txt*' contains the directory/path to another unique file. Suppose we want to parse '*a.txt*' line-by-line, extract the path in string format, and then use a tool such as vim to process the file at this path, and so on.

After going through this thread - [Read a file line by line assigning the value to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable), I wrote the following script, say '*open-file.sh*' on bash (I'm new to it)

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  vim -c ":q" -cq $line # Just open the file and close it using :q 
done < "$1"
```

We would then run the above script as  -

```
./open-file.sh a.txt
```

The problem is that although the path to a new file is correctly specified by $line, when vim opens the file, vim continues to receive the text contained in '*a.txt*' as a command. How can I write a script where I can correctly obtain the path from '*a.txt*', open it using vim, and then continue parsing the remaining lines in '*a.txt*' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
vim -c ":q" -cq $line
```

With:

```
vim -c ":q" -cq "$line" </dev/tty
```

The redirection `</dev/tty` tells `vim` to take its standard input from the terminal.  Without that, the standard input for `vim` is `"$1"`.

Also, it is good practice to put `$line` in double-quotes to protect it from *word splitting*, etc.

Lastly, while `vim` is excellent for interactive work, if your end-goal is fully automated processing of each file, you might want to consider tools such as `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: Will check out the other tools you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure of your ultimate goal, this shell command will execute vim once per line in `a.txt`:

`xargs -o -n1 vim -c ':q' < a.txt`

As explained in the comments to [Read a file line by line assigning the value to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable), the issue you're encountering is due to the fact that vim is an interactive program and thus continues to read input from `$line`.

Comment: `xargs -o` is not available in my `GNU findutils 4.7.0`. From `man xargs` it seems `-o` is specific to BSD. **Quote:** *`xargs sh -c 'emacs "$@" < /dev/tty' emacs` [...] This example achieves the  same  effect as BSD's -o option, but in a more flexible and portable way.*

Comment: Interesting and good to be aware of. I am also using `GNU findutils 4.7.0` on Ubuntu and the man page states that `-o` was added for better compatibility with BSD.

Comment: That's strange. The full version is *`xargs (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git` `Copyright (C) 2016 [...]`*. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS in the Windows subsystem for Linux (WSL). When I try to execute the command I get `xargs: invalid option -- 'o'`.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 so I guess they added it fairly recently.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was [already mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable#comment31864084_10929511) under the answer you based your script on.

`vim` is consuming `stdin` which is given to the loop by `done < $1`. We can observe the same behavior in the following example:

```
$ while read i; do cat; done < <(seq 3)
2
3
```

`<(seq 3)` simulates a file with the three lines `1`, `2`, and `3`. Instead of three silent iterations we get only one iteration and the output `2` and `3`.

`stdin` is not only passed to `read` in the head of the loop, but also to `cat` in the body of the loop. Therefore `read` reads one line, the loop is entered, `cat` reads all remaining lines, `stdin` is empty, `read` has nothing to read anymore, the loop exits.

You could circumvent the problem by redirecting something to `vim`, however there is an even better way. You don't need the loop at all:

```
< "$1" xargs -d\\n -n1 vim -c :q -cq
```

`xargs` will execute `vim` once for every line in the file given by `$1`.

Comment: Ah yes, the answer was in the comment.