# unable to read a file in while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop

I've the below code:

```
#!/bin/bash

. ~/.bash_profile

dt=$(date +"%Y.%m.%d")

if [[ "$#" -eq '0' ]] || [[ "$#" -eq '1' ]]
then
echo -e "Not correct usage"
exit 1
fi

tar zvxf $SHARE/*.gz -C $SHARE/landing/

sleep 3

ops () {
//
some sets of command
//
}

while read -r line
do
if [[ "$1" == "A" ]] || [[ "$1" == "B" ]] || [[ "$1" == "C" ]] && [[ "$2" =~ "$line" ]] || [[ "$2" == "ALL" ]]
then
ops
fi
done < $SHARE/landing/dir/ApprovedList."$1"
```

When i run the script, i can see that it's able to untar the .gz file and place it into the folder :`$SHARE/landing/`

But i guess it's not able to read the file and perform the operations inside the ops function, below is the last line of output i'm getting after running the script in interactive mode:

```
+ read -r line
```

Any help is most welcome!!!

Comment: May I recommend using shellcheck (https://www.shellcheck.net/) on the script first.

Comment: does the `ops` function include programs that consume stdin?

Comment: @glennjackman: basically ops function contains some cp,mv commands and uses the variable `line`.

Comment: Look into shellcheck.net, your `=~` may not do what you expect.

Comment: Maybe a 'mv' inside the ops function is trying to overwrite an existing file and is asking you to answer 'yes' or 'no'. If you always want to overwrite, use `cp --force ...` and `mv --force ...`.

Comment: @MichaelJaros: I checked in shellcheck.net, doesn't seems to be an issue.

Comment: I think you should let us in on what exactly the function 'ops' does. This way it's a blackbox, and answering your question remains a guessing game.

Comment: That multiple condition `if` with all the embedded `||` and `&&` might work, but looks too fragile to me. From the [BashFAQ}(https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Control_Operators_.28.26.26_and_.7C.7C.29): "It's best not to get overzealous when dealing with conditional operators. They can make your script hard to understand, especially for a person that's assigned to maintain it and didn't write it themselves." Don't try to do everything in one command. Maybe the `&&` represents an embedded pair of `case` statements. :) Also, some error checking/handling seems in order.

Comment: You have not shown us the contents of the file, or the command line parameters. There's no way we can help you. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: How do you think `ops` is using the line?  You didn't pass it as an argument.  Is it reading it from stdin?  If so, see @glennjackman's comment.

Comment: The `while read` loop won't process the last line in the input file if it's not terminated (a fairly common situation).  See [Read a file line by line assigning the value to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10929453/4154375).

Comment: If this were a [mcve], it could just be three lines. One `while read -r line; do` line, one `echo "$line"`, and a `done`... plus whatever the *shortest possible* amount of extra complexity needed to cause the actual bug is. Here, we have something that's basically certain to be completely unrelated to the while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please show the input format, the argument format, and some explanation of those. In the meantime, tweaked for readability and error handling - edit to taste. YMMV.

```
#!/bin/bash

. ~/.bash_profile

ops () {  # do some stuff
  : some sets of commands ...
}

die() {
  printf "%s\n\n Use: $0 x y z ...\n\n" "$1" >&2
  kill -term $$ # exit in function behaves like return
}

# dt=$(date +"%Y.%m.%d") # unused

case "$#" in
0|1) die "Insufficient arguments" ;;
esac

tar zvxf "$SHARE"/*.gz -C "$SHARE/landing/" || die "tar failed"

sleep 3
infile="$SHARE/landing/dir/ApprovedList.$1"
[[ -e "$infile" ]] || die "$infile does not exist"
[[ -r "$infile" ]] || die "$infile is nor readable by $0 as $LOGNAME"
while read -r line
do case "$1" in
   A|B|C) case "$2" in
          *"$line"*|ALL) ops ;;
                      *) : data does not match, skipping ;;
          esac ;;
       *) die "Invalid arg1 '$1'";;
   esac
done < "$infile"
```

---

#### Notes:

If you require *exactly* 2 arguments, then let's check exactly that:

```
die() {
  printf "%s\n\n Use: $0 x y\n\n" "$1" >&2
  kill -term $$ # exit in function behaves like return
}
```

and

```
case "$#" in
2) ;;
*) die "Incorrect # of arguments" ;;
esac
```

---

Also, better than the `kill` - add a `trap` at the top:

```
trap 'echo >&2 "ERROR in $0($BASH_SOURCE) at line $LINENO: [$BASH_COMMAND]"; exit $LINENO;' ERR
```

and use a literal error return in the function.

```
die() {
  printf "%s\n\n Use: $0 x y\n\n" "$1" >&2
  return 1
}
```

Comment: `exit` in a function behaves like return only if the function is in a subshell.

Comment: That's an excellent point - but unless this whole script is being `source`d, it would be, yes? Still, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I think you want `case "$2" in "*$line*"|ALL) ops ;;` to mimic the `=~` operator.

Comment: Although that implies that the OP meant to write `[[ $line =~ $2 ]]`, which seems the more natural thing to write.

Comment: But he needs to be able to skip the line matching if `$2` was `ALL`, yes?

Comment: I think it could be written `[[ $2 == ALL ]] || [[ $line =~ $2 ]]`, but your case statement is much better.

Comment: Err, surely that should be `in *"$line"*|ALL) ops ;;`, with the `*`s unquoted?

Comment: Yeah, I fixed that when I added it in.

Answer (score 0):

The check (except for `[[ "$2" =~ "$line" ]]`)

```
if [[ "$1" == "A" ]] || [[ "$1" == "B" ]] || [[ "$1" == "C" ]] && [[ "$2" =~ "$line" ]] || [[ "$2" == "ALL" ]]
```

doesn't change inside the while-loop. So better check once before entering the while-loop.
So now you want to perform `ops` for each line of `$SHARE/landing/dir/ApprovedList."$1"`.

You can use

```
xargs -a "$SHARE/landing/dir/ApprovedList.$1" -L 1 ops
```

EDIT:
When you have a simple check to perform for each line, you can move this check into the `ops` function.
First save `$2` before entering the function:

```
to_be_checked="$2"
...
ops() {
   [[ "$0" =~ "${to_be_checked}" ]] && return
```

Comment: ...well, *exactly one* condition changes, `[[ "$2" =~ "$line" ]]`. Though that is very, very unlikely to be what the OP really wants (do they really intend to check if the line is an *exact substring* of the 2nd argument? The other way around, or the other way around *and* doing a regex check rather than a substring check, seems more likely).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  I was partially blind. First I wanted to suggest to use `case "$1" in` but noticed a `$2`. Then I stopped processing that line.