# Bash using cut to separate an IP and Port

Tags: bash

I am trying to pass an ip and port to my bash script from a list of devices but the script is reading it as multiple devices instead of port. So in the example from below it's trying to telnet to 4 devices as it's reading the ports as a device.

```
for device in `cat device-list.txt`;
do
  hostname=$(echo $device | cut -d : -f 1)
  port=$(echo $port | cut -d : -f 2)
  ./script.exp $device $username $password $port ;
done
```

I am trying to use cut to take the port and pass it through as a variable so my telnet should be e.g. abc.abc.com 30040 as one device and so on.

```
 # Telnet
spawn telnet $hostname $port
```

This is my list of devices

```
abc.abc.com 30040
abc.abc.com 30041
```

I have tried searching this site already for answers.

Answer (score 4):

I see two errors (lines 4 & 5). It should be

```
 for device in `cat device-list.txt`;
 do
   hostname=$(echo $device | cut -d : -f 1)
   port=$(echo $device | cut -d : -f 2)
   ./script.exp $hostname $username $password $port ;
 done
```

Comment: Same output, still sees 4 IP's instead of 2 IP's and 2 ports

Comment: ah. I missed what your device-list.txt file looked like. Assumed that you had the `cut` command properly written.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Bash built-in `read` function to extract `hostname` and `port` from the lines in a loop:

```
while read -r hostname port || [[ -n $hostname ]] ; do
    ./script.exp "$hostname" "$username" "$password" "$port"
done <device-list.txt
```

- See [Read a file line by line assigning the value to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10929453/4154375) for information about reading files line by line in Bash.
- I've added quotes to stop [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) warnings, and make the code safer.
- See [How to loop over the lines of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7011/264812) for an explanation of why the code in the question doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

@pjh has the correct answer.

But here's some notes on your script:

1. you iterate over all the *words* of the file, rather than its *lines*.
2. using `cut -d :`, you specify the delimiter between fields as `:`.
   However, in your file you don't use `:` as the delimiter, but space ()
3. you calculate the `$hostname` variable by parsing `$device`, but then you use `$device` when calling the script
4. you calculate the `$port` variable by parsing the `$port` variable, which doesn't make any sense.

Here's an example on how to parse each line with `cut`:

```sh
cat device-list.txt | while read device; do
  hostname=$(echo $device | cut -d" " -f 1)
  port=$(echo $device | cut -d" " -f 2)
  ./script.exp $hostname $username $password $port
done
```