# Bash | oneliner | curl | Trying to loop through a file and feed it to curl but it throws an error?

Tags: bash, sorting, for-loop, curl, sed

I am trying to loop through the `file.txt` which has domains like `%.google.com` and use `curl` with URL `crt.sh` to extract HTTPS websites subdomains from certificate.

Unfortunately it throws an error

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 20
```

*script.sh*

```
for i in $(cat file.txt); do echo""; echo "crtsh $i"; echo ""; curl -s https://crt.sh/?q\=$1\&output\=json | jq -r '.[].name_value' | sed 's/\*\.//g' | sort -u; echo ""; done
```

Comment: Are you trying to [read a file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable)?

Comment: This is a `jq` error, meaning the "JSON" is not a correct JSON. For example: `echo '[{"name_value": 3x2}]' | jq -r '.[].name_value'`. Inspect what exactly you are getting from your `curl`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  yes, i have a list of domains which i need to feed to this ```curl -s https://crt.sh/?q\=$1\&output\=json | jq -r '.[].name_value' | sed 's/\*\.//g' | sort -u``` so i'm trying to add a loop

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to [read the input file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/), you need to change your approach slightly.

The following example is working in my environment and has some enhancements for debugging and to get a better understanding.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo"";

  # Added for easier debugging and understanding
  URL="${line}";
  echo ${URL};

  echo "";

  # Added switches for easier debugging
  #   -i, include the HTTP-header in the output
  #   -w, display http_code on stdout after a completed and successful operation
  curl --silent -x "localhost:3128" --include 'https://crt.sh/?q=${URL}&output=json' --write-out "\n\n%{http_code}\n"; # | jq -r '.[].name_value' | sed 's/\*\.//g' | sort -u;

  curl -s 'https://crt.sh/?q=${URL}&output=json' | jq -r '.[].name_value' | sed 's/\*\.//g' | sort -u;

  echo "";
done < URLs.txt
```

It would also be possible to change it to an one-liner.