# Replace every occurrence of a word with each line from an list-file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I want to name each .tar file in the code below and name it based on a list-file that contains the names, but I don't want to mess with the exclusion tag. I have a list file and I was thinking of using a text editor and adding cvf to the beginning of each line I have in a list and then use sed to replace the string **cvf**, thus adding the flag and then the name follows.

**i.e.**

`cvf name1
cvf name2
cvf name3`

I tried using `sed 's/cvf/word2/g' input.file` and as expected it only replaces cvf with the replacement word. I want the replacement word (word2) to change and to be each line from a list file.

**Code I want modified:**

`stage ('Zip Repo340') {
            steps {
            sh"""
                tar --exclude='*.tar' -cvf .tar *
            """
        stage ('Zip Repo341') {
            steps {
            sh"""
                tar --exclude='*.tar' -cvf .tar *
            """
        stage ('Zip Repo342') {
            steps {
            sh"""
                tar --exclude='*.tar' -cvf .tar *
            """`

I have 340 of these repositories and I want to name them based on a list file that I have.

List file:

`name1
name2
name3`

Desired output:

`stage ('Zip Repo340') {
            steps {
            sh"""
                tar --exclude='*.tar' -cvf name1.tar *
            """
        stage ('Zip Repo341') {
            steps {
            sh"""
                tar --exclude='*.tar' -cvf name2.tar *
            """
        stage ('Zip Repo342') {
            steps {
            sh"""
                tar --exclude='*.tar' -cvf name3.tar *
            """`

I can add cvf to each line of my list file, but if there's a more elegant solution I'm all ears. The biggest issue I'm having is running the sed replacement command and have the replacement word come from a list file.

Comment: What's the relationship between the list and the tar?

Comment: The relationship is that the list contains the names for the .tar files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll do it. Assuming `File_1.txt` has your code and `File_2.txt` has the names to replace.

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; do
    sed -i "0,/cvf \.tar/{s|cvf \.tar|cvf ${line}\.tar|}" File_1.txt
done < File_2.txt
```

What is happening here?

1. `sed -i <gobledegook> File_1.txt` We are making changes to File_1.txt. What changes? Lets explore the `sed` script that is the `<gobledegook>`
2. `"0,/<gobledegook>` This says we will be searching for the **first** occurrence of *something*
3. `"0,/cvf \.tar/<gobledegook>` That *something* that we will be searching for will be `cvf .tar` We had to say `\.tar` because `.` is a "special character"
4. `"0,/cvf \.tar/{s|<gobledegook>}` We are saying here that on the line that our search string exists we want to do another sed script. The new sed script is defined in `{}` I decided to use `|` as a delimiter for the second sed script to help distinguish the two.
5. `"0,/cvf \.tar/{s|cvf \.tar|}` We are going to replace `cvf .tar` with *something*
6. `"0,/cvf \.tar/{s|cvf \.tar|cvf ${line}\.tar|}"` We are going to replace `cvf .tar` with `cfv ${line}.tar` where `${line}` is the current line from `File_2.txt`

[Very similar to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60874910/using-sed-to-add-text-after-a-pattern-but-the-added-text-comes-from-a-list-file/60875476?noredirect=1#comment107808724_60875476)

Comment: WOW! It just works! You are so amazing and I can't thank you enough. I have been searching for this for quite some time and you are my hero. I will use this A LOT in the future and I even named my script-file Lenna. Thanks for the quick and informative response, hope you're staying safe in the quarantine era.

Comment: Thank you, any chance to spread some ```sed``` love haha. You stay safe too!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```sh
SCRIPT_NAME='outScript.sh'
while read filename; do
  # Replace only the first match:
  sed "0,/-cvf \.tar/s/-cvf \.tar/-cvf ${filename}.tar/" $SCRIPT_NAME > /tmp/tmp.sh
  mv /tmp/tmp.sh $SCRIPT_NAME
done < all_filenames.txt
```

Basically, you go through your names file, and for each name, you replace the first non-replaced match

Comment: Alright, I've got it substituting and naming the files, but it's currently running the command for every occurrence of the pattern, so I end up with 340 lines named the same, another 340 lines named the same as the second variable and I can't get it to only do the first occurence.

`while read var;
do
  sed -e "s|cvf|${var}|g1" test2.txt

done < shortened.txt
`