# How to access data when they are redirected using "<" from file?

Tags: bash

How can I read the file line by line if i get it like this:

```
./script.sh < data.txt
```

Where do the data from the file data.txt go?

Comment: it is redirected to the STDIN hande and can be read from inside the script.sh
see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10929511/4271392

Comment: thank you @FangQ, got it to work.