# How to match the syntax in file if matches display success or fail

Tags: linux, shell

I have a scenario where i have following below data in Student file

My `Student.txt` data input, need to follow a pattern, on each line need to contains three infos separated by `/` as follows:

`NAME/SURNAME/COUNTRY`

So, below I have an example of file that is fine:

```
    RAM/ABC/INDIA
    RAJ/XYZ/DELHI
    VIRAJ/FDS/GUJRAT
```

---

### **WHAT IS EXPECTED:**

Each and every record in file should match with that syntax: `NAME/SURNAME/COUNTRY`.

If anyone fails then, the overall status should be displayed as failed, with the message `syntax does not match`, otherwise, mark as success.

---

### WHAT'S HAPPENING:

If I pass data to above code like below:

```
    RAM/ABC/INDIA
    RAJ/XYZ/DELHI
    VIRAJ/FDS/
```

When I execute the my code, I don't get any error saying failed: 
`syntax does not match` it simply check upto below two records

```
    RAM/ABC/INDIA
    RAJ/XYZ/DELHI
```

The last record in file, that is `VIRAJ/FDS/` does not check and not thrown error failed: `syntax does not match`

**My code:**

```sh
    for i in `cat /demo/Student.txt`
      do 
      check=`echo $i | cut -d '/'-f3`
      if [[ -z $check ]];
      then 
        echo failed syntax does not match NAME/SURNAME/COUNTRY
        exit 1 
      fi 
    done
```

Comment: You have to explain what happened and what you expected to happen instead. "Does not work" doesn't tell me any of that.

Comment: @BenjaminW. i have updated the question now i added my error

Comment: @BenjaminW.  can you try it my code and sample data

Comment: I get `cut: the delimiter must be a single character`, there's a blank missing after `'/'`.

Comment: When I fix that typo, your code works as expected (doesn't follow a few best practices, though – see https://stackoverflow.com/q/10929453/3266847).

Comment: @BenjaminW.  bro the file data is only like that if any of the record does not match according to the syntax then should dispay failed ..... last record VIRAJ/FDS/

Comment: I understand. What I'm telling you is a) there is a typo in your code which makes it display an error you're not mentioning, so I don't know if it was just not properly copy-pasted or if you're running different code and b) when I fix that typo, I can't reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using regular expressions, as you can see here:

```
grep "[A-Z]/[A-Z]*/[A-Z]" test.txt
```

This shows the following lines:

```
RAM/ABC/INDIA
RAJ/XYZ/DELHI
```

Which is caused by following entries which match:

```
M/ABC/I
J/XYZ/D
```

If you use `grep -v` you find the lines which don't match. Launching a `wc -l`, you find if there are any of such lines and in case yes, you can show your error message.

Some regular expression syntaxes use `+` as a way to say "one or more entries" (instead of `*` which means "zero or more entries") but it depends on your system's OS if this works or not.

Can you tell me if this is working out for you?