# Bash doesn't print string with question mark in for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, echo, file-read

I have a text file with the following contents,

```
My test
strings
that dont have
a question 
mark except this line?
but not
these two
```

and when i try to read the file in bash using, for example,

```
ph_lines="/path/to/file.txt"
for l in $(cat "$ph_lines") 
do
    echo "$l"
done
```

everything prints on the output except for the string with the question mark in it.

I have tried using `while read line; echo line; done < $filename` and it still has the same problem

The only thing that would work to capture all of the lines is when i used sed to remove question marks.

```
for l in $(cat ${ph_lines} | sed $'s/\?//' )
```

Thank you!

Comment: You didn't prefix your variable with `$` as in:  `while read line; echo "$line"; done < filename`

Comment: https://shellcheck.net for validating your script.

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 is useful reading.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The code in your post does not have the problem you describe. Your actual script has something to the effect of `IFS=$'\n'; shopt -s nullglob;` in it, which is necessary to reproduce the issue. Protip: the easiest way to ensure your question is complete and captures all necessary details is to copy-paste the code from your post into a new file and testing that first

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue. The word with the question mark is printed the same way as all other ones.

Answer (score 0):

To correctly read from a file, use the example from [Read a file line by line assigning the value to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10929511/1899640):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done < my_filename.txt
```

The difference is not that it's a while loop (because you've tried that), but because this loop is correctly quoted. The problem you're seeing happens because you secretly enabled `nullglob` first, and then neglected to quote:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ var='question?'

$ echo "$var"
question?

$ echo $var
(blank line)
```

Unquoted expansion causes pathname expansion, and since you enabled `nullglob` and have no matching files, the previous example shows nothing. If you had some matching files, you'd see those instead:

```
$ touch questions question2

$ echo $var
question2 questions
```

You can set up [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net/) in your editor to get automatic warnings about these issues.

Comment: tbh dont even know why i have shopt -s nullglob turned on.

A lot of the script i'm writing is copy pasted from some snips here and there.

I just learned about spellcheck... I have a lot of issues.

Thanks for the info and help!

Comment: There is a minor issue with proposed solution - for the case that the input file has lines starting with '-', which could activate any of the `echo` command line options (e.g., '-e').  Consider using 'printf '%s\n' "$line"` instead. too bad  `echo` does not support `--` to mark the end of the options, which is the common way to indicate end of options.