# Parse through Input file Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, parsing, parameters

Attempting to parse through a file

Contents of file: Directory|days|recursive|delete_directory|prefix|logfile

```
/testing/bash/folder1|7|Y|N||
/testing/bash/folder2|8|Y|Y||
```

The script written is below:

```
#/bin/bash

parameters=${1}
param_array=()

IFS='|'
for parameter in ${parameters}
do
        param_array+=(parameter)
done
IFS=${OIFS}

dir_name=${param_array[0]}
days_old=${param_array[1]}
recursive=${param_array[2]}
delete_dir=${param_array[3]}
prefix=${param_array[4]}
log_file=${param_array[5]}

echo ${dir_name}
echo ${days_old}
echo ${recursive}
echo ${delete_dir}
echo ${prefix}
echo ${log_file}
```

The script posts the results below:

```
./parameters trim_dir.dat
parameter
```

The desired results are below:

```
/testing/bash/folder1
7
Y
N
 

/testing/bash/folder2
8
Y
Y
```

Comment: Please consider making your own life much easier by writing a single line at a time and testing that it works before proceding, instead of writing the whole script and then trying to debug all the problems at the same time. For starters, you don't open or read from the file at any point. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable) for how to read a file line by line in bash

Comment: The line `/testing/bash/folder1|7|Y|N||` has 5 fields whereas your format has 6 fields.

Comment: Additionally, you don't need a `for` loop. Simply use `IFS=\| read -ra param_array <<< "$parameters"`, thus you don't need to restore the `IFS` either.

Comment: Extending @M.NejatAydin's comment: if you want to read from a file (specified by `$1`), use `while IFS=\| read -ra param_array; do ... done <"$1"`, or maybe skip the array and use `while IFS=\| read -r dir_name days_old recursive delete_dir prefix log_file; do ... done <"$1"`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin, no that's 6 fields, the last 2 are empty.

Comment: @glennjackman `IFS=\| read -a arr <<< '/testing/bash/folder1|7|Y|N||'; echo ${#arr[*]}` prints `5`. `IFS` is used as a field terminator, not a field separator, in bash.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It's still odd though: with `IFS='|' read -ra x <<<"a|b|c"`  we get 3 fields even though the last field is not terminated.

Comment: @glennjackman This behaviour of `IFS` is strange in itself. It is explained [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#IFS.3D.2C_read_-ra_fields_.3C.3C.3C_.22.24csv_line.22) as historical reasons.