# Automatically git clone into a unique destination directory

Tags: bash, git

I have a few hundred repos in a text file that I need to clone.  A fair number of the repos have the same name (e.g., forks) and hence, the same destination directory.  Is there a way to clone the repos with unique destination names?

Example:

```
for i in $(cat repolist.txt); do git clone $i $ORGNAME.$REPONAME; done
```

Or something like that?

Comment: What is the format of the `repolist.txt` file? Like an example url

Comment: Just a list of repo URLs...one URL per line (e.g., https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework)

Comment: You can use `||` to combine commands such that the second one only executes if the first fails, and you can use `$(basename $(dirname $i))` to get the ORGNAME and `$(basename $i)` to get the REPONAME.

Comment: You should read your file [differently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10929453/3266847).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all your URLs have one of these forms:

```
https://github.com/user1/repo1.git
https://github.com/user2/repo1.git  
git@github.com:user3/repo2.git  
git@github.com:user4/repo2.git
```

you can define a Bash function like this:

```
clone() {
  local url=$1
  local repo=${url%.git} # remove .git suffix if need be
  repo=${repo##*/}       # remove largest prefix upto last slash
  local org=${url%/*}    # remove suffix from last slash
  org=${org##*[/:]}      # remove largest prefix upto slash or colon
  ( set -x;  # verbose mode
    git clone "$url" "$org.$repo" )
}
```

Then you can do indeed:

```
for i in $(cat repolist.txt); do clone "$i"; done
```

One advantage of using this syntax (`${parameter#word}`, `${parameter%word}`, etc.) over `basename` and `dirname` is that no extra process is spinned, since this [parameter expansion feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) is builtin in Bash.

Finally, as explained in the SO question [Read a file line by line assigning the value to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10929453/9164010) (mentioned by [Benjamin W.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63513606/automatically-git-clone-into-a-unique-destination-directory/63513858#comment112314481_63513606)), you can avoid the `$(cat repolist.txt)` phrasing and run the following command:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do clone "$line"; done < repolist.txt
```

which is **more efficient**; and also **more robust** in case a line contains spaces (even if this situation won't occur here).