# How do I import lines from another file and put them into variables in my current script without using sed, grep, awk, find?

Tags: bash, shell

How do I read the contents of a file and then put them into different variables in another script?

For example, let's say this is student_1.item, which contains exactly these three lines:

```
student_1 Sally Johnson
8 1 
Mr. Ortiz
```

In another script, say script1.bash, I want to read the values in script2.bash and print the information so that the following is displayed:

```
Student number: student_1
Student name: Sally Johnson
Age: 8
Grade Level: 1
Teacher: Mr. Ortiz
```

How do I do this without using find, grep, sed, and awk?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: This is a good read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable

Comment: The concept is what I need help with for a lab assignment, yes.

Comment: It's unclear why you need 2 scripts to acheieve your output. You'll need to show more code here for us to understand that. Good luck.

Comment: Bizarrely we often get the question "how do I read a file line per line, even if there are spaces in the lines?".  Here you want the opposite.  **If** your input file will always be that format, you could do that.  It uses a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

With three `read` commands and a `printf`:

```
{ read num name; read age gl; read teacher; } < student_1.item 
printf \
'Student number: %s
Student name: %s
Age: %s
Grade Level: %s
Teacher: %s\n' $num "$name" $age $gl "$teacher"
```

Output:

```
Student number: student_1
Student name: Sally Johnson
Age: 8
Grade Level: 1
Teacher: Mr. Ortiz
```