# bash script - for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, find

Let's say I have a txt file like:

```
CGND_01234    CGND-HRA-00736
CGND_34563    CGND-HRA-00567
...
```

How do I create a for loop for the below line in bash that iterates every line in the file?

```
find ./${first_word_in_the_first_line} -name "${second_word_in_the_first_line}*.bam" -type f 
find ./${first_word_in_the_second_line} -name "${second_word_in_the_second_line}*.bam" -type f
...
```

Answer (score 6):

A `while read` loop is a common way to [read a file line-by-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable). Conveniently, if you pass multiple variable names to `read` it will also split the line at the same time.

```
while read -r dir file; do
    find "$dir" -name "$file*.bam" -type f 
done < file.txt
```

Comment: This should probably use `read -r` (re. `shellcheck`) and a different FD (`read -u9` & `done 9< file.txt`, for example) in case OP wants to use a stdin-swallowing command inside the loop.

Comment: I added `read -r`. I'll pass on the different FD idea; don't want to overcomplicate matters.

Comment: Worked. Thank you @JohnKugelman

Also I had to use **fromdos** to convert dos to UNIX, since my text file was in dos