# sort by datetime format in bash

Tags: bash, sorting, datetime

this is an example of my data

```
ip=1.2.3.4, setup_time=05:58:38.617 GMT Tue Mar 16 2021, foo=moshe, bar=haim
ip=2.3.4.5, setup_time=05:59:30.260 GMT Tue Mar 16 2021, foo=moshe2, bar=haim2
```

i would like to be able to sort by the `setup_time` column in bash. I know that I can't use `sort` because sort allow only sort by string matching and this is not a format of `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` so string sorting is not possible.

so any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

thank you

#update

ok to better understand what i'm trying to achieve i created the folowing file named `1`:

```
ip=1.2.3.4, setup_time=06:58:38.617 GMT Tue Mar 16 2021, foo=moshe, bar=haim
ip=2.3.4.5, setup_time=05:59:30.260 GMT Tue Mar 17 2021, foo=moshe2, bar=haim2
ip=2.3.4.5, setup_time=06:50:30.260 GMT Tue Mar 18 2021, foo=moshe2, bar=haim2
```

so I executed this:

```
cat 1 | sed 's/, /!/g' | sort -t '!' -k2,2
```

what i did here is replaced `,`  with `!` so i can use a delimiter in sort, the problem is that sort is doing string sorting and not timestamp kind of sorting so the output is:

```
ip=2.3.4.5!setup_time=05:59:30.260 GMT Tue Mar 17 2021!foo=moshe2!bar=haim2
ip=2.3.4.5!setup_time=06:50:30.260 GMT Tue Mar 18 2021!foo=moshe2!bar=haim2
ip=1.2.3.4!setup_time=06:58:38.617 GMT Tue Mar 16 2021!foo=moshe!bar=haim
```

Comment: I suggest to use a [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

Comment: @Cyrus - added info, so in general i should use a programming language for that? it can't be done in pure bash ?

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sort is able to deal with month names, thanks to the option `M`

No need to change `,`  into `!`. Use the white space as delimiter and just issue:

```
LC_ALL=en sort -k7nr -k5Mr -k6nr -k2r sample
```

If you use this as content of the file `sample`:

```
ip=2.3.4.5, setup_time=05:59:30.260 GMT Tue Apr 1 2021, foo=moshe2, bar=haim2
ip=2.3.4.5, setup_time=05:59:30.260 GMT Tue Mar 17 2021, foo=moshe2, bar=haim2
ip=1.2.3.4, setup_time=06:58:38.617 GMT Tue Mar 16 2021, foo=moshe, bar=haim
ip=1.2.3.4, setup_time=06:58:38.617 GMT Tue Feb 28 2021, foo=moshe, bar=haim
ip=2.3.4.5, setup_time=06:50:30.260 GMT Tue Mar 18 2020, foo=moshe2, bar=haim2
ip=2.3.4.5, setup_time=06:50:30.260 GMT Tue Mar 18 2021, foo=moshe2, bar=haim2
```

you will get this as output:

```
ip=2.3.4.5, setup_time=05:59:30.260 GMT Tue Apr 1 2021, foo=moshe2, bar=haim2
ip=2.3.4.5, setup_time=06:50:30.260 GMT Tue Mar 18 2021, foo=moshe2, bar=haim2
ip=2.3.4.5, setup_time=05:59:30.260 GMT Tue Mar 17 2021, foo=moshe2, bar=haim2
ip=1.2.3.4, setup_time=06:58:38.617 GMT Tue Mar 16 2021, foo=moshe, bar=haim
ip=1.2.3.4, setup_time=06:58:38.617 GMT Tue Feb 28 2021, foo=moshe, bar=haim
ip=2.3.4.5, setup_time=06:50:30.260 GMT Tue Mar 18 2020, foo=moshe2, bar=haim2
```

Specifying `-k7` means to sort on the seventh field. The `r` option reverses the order of sorting to descending. The `M` option sorts according the name of the month. The `n` option sorts numerically. To sort on the time, just consider the whole second field (beginning with the string `setup_time=`) as a fixed length string using `-k2`.

`LC_ALL=en` in the begin of the command line tells the system to use the English names of the months.

Comment: Why is `Mar 16 2021` before `Feb 28 2021`?

Comment: @Cyrus: the order is descending: the oldest entries are below and the newest above, as asked by the PO.

Comment: Thank you, I had simply overlooked that.

Comment: hi.. i needed -k2r also not just -k2. thank you so much it works beautifully.

Comment: @ufk: Sorry, I overlooked that. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A solution involving awk:

```
awk '
{
    year = substr($7, 1, length($7)-1)
    cmd ="date --date=\""$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$year"\" +%s"
    cmd | getline var
    print var, $0
    close(cmd)
}' file | sort -k 1 | cut -f 1- -d' '
```

The trick is that date --date="GMT Tue Mar 18 2021" will parse the date heuristically (meaning it will also work with gdate --date="GMT Tue 18 Mar 2021"), and then you can print only the seconds since epoch.

awk will output the seconds as first column, you sort by it, then you remove the first column from the result.

Biggest advantage of this solution is that it will work for other types of date formats (within reason of course).

Note1: for this to work you need GNU date (on Mac OS gdate, for example)

Note2: instead of awk you could use also bash with while/read (as in [Read a file line by line assigning the value to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable)), but awk is rather standard, so not sure if it is a big difference for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `sort` with month name support -- use that. Pierre's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67607765/298607) is elegant!

If you don't, convert the date to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (which sorts lexicographically) and use a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) or a Decorate / Sort / Undecorate pattern.

The easiest, since the date you have is non standard, is use Perl to decorate, sort to sort on the first field, then cut to undecorate (remove the added field):

```
perl -lnE '
BEGIN{ 
%m2n = qw(Jan 01  Feb 02  Mar 03  Apr 04  May 05  Jun 06
          Jul 07  Aug 08  Sep 09  Oct 10 Nov 11 Dec 12
);}

m/setup_time=([\d:]+).*?(\w\w\w) (\d\d?) (\d\d\d\d),/;
$mon=$m2n{$2};
say "$4$mon$3$1\t$_"' YourFile | sort -t $'\t' -r -k1,1 | cut -d $'\t' -f2-
```

Using pierre's data, prints:

```
ip=2.3.4.5, setup_time=05:59:30.260 GMT Tue Apr 1 2021, foo=moshe2, bar=haim2
ip=2.3.4.5, setup_time=06:50:30.260 GMT Tue Mar 18 2021, foo=moshe2, bar=haim2
ip=2.3.4.5, setup_time=05:59:30.260 GMT Tue Mar 17 2021, foo=moshe2, bar=haim2
ip=1.2.3.4, setup_time=06:58:38.617 GMT Tue Mar 16 2021, foo=moshe, bar=haim
ip=1.2.3.4, setup_time=06:58:38.617 GMT Tue Feb 28 2021, foo=moshe, bar=haim
ip=2.3.4.5, setup_time=06:50:30.260 GMT Tue Mar 18 2020, foo=moshe2, bar=haim2
```