# Generate copies of a code with just one line different in all of them

Tags: bash, shell

I need to make a copy of a large code and replace just a name in the code. I have to do this multiple times with a list of names.

eg:

I have the names:

```
Jay
Joy
Jane
Juda
```

and I have an example code/text:

```
print("Hi");
Print("Hello")
print("Jay"); # here
```

I want the output to be like:

```
print("Hi");
Print("Hello")
print("Jay"); # here

print("Hi");
Print("Hello")
print("Joy"); # here

print("Hi");
Print("Hello")
print("Jane"); # here
```

ie, just changing one part of the code but have to repeat all the other steps.

Comment: What about making a loop?

Comment: What kind of code, in a file, variables, arrays? In a file do a loop read line by line and output your values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable

Comment: No `Juda` line? How important is it for the output to **not** have a trailing blank line?

Answer (score 0):

```bash
awk '{printf("print(\"Hi\");\nprint(\"Hello\");\nprint(\"%s\"); # here\n\n",$0)}' input_file.txt
```

UPDATE: as I understand your comment, you need a template

```bash
template-file:
bla
bla bla
bla %NAME% bla
bla

script:
IFS=$'\n'
for i in `cat names`; do
sed "s/%NAME%/$i/" template-file
done
```

Comment: This will work with this example, yes. But unfortunately  i have a large code ( like 20 lines) and want to make copies of them just changing one word

Comment: @AbhiRaj : 20 lines you might as well do it by hand

Comment: @AbhiRaj You have 3 files: 1. template-file 2. names 3. script Run it in BASH. not in powershell.