# How to decode base64 from each line in file in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, base64

I have a file that contains many lines of base64 encoded text. I usually use `base64 -d` command to decode a single base64 string, but can I apply this command to each line in a file? Of course I can write a simple python script for this purpose, but I'm looking for more elegant and faster way using bash only.
File contents example:

```
TEdVVURQT1NNS0FEQVZVWlZYTkQ=
V1dOUERXR0ZGT1VEUkdWTUFTQ1o=
U1NKV0pNSkVBSEtVU0hESEVWTkw=
Q0ZVTllUU05HUE9NR1dEV0lXSVY=
U1RZWVZOVE5ESUFVSUNBU1NNRU4=
SkhFQkJTQUhIWkxWSVBXS0VDSUI=
SE5GUFNVWU5YRVZVVktCWUZNS1E=
SUtZTlRCWFRKS0FFSEtNWlNWS0Q=
TVBSWlVKQU5BRlNDVE9JVkVDQ1A=
Q0hIT1ZOVVhQSFBGTlVUSERUQlQ=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`base64 -d` will do what you want out of the box on my system:

```
$ echo one | base64  > file.txt
$ echo two | base64  >> file.txt
$ echo three | base64  >> file.txt

$ cat file.txt 
b25lCg==
dHdvCg==
dGhyZWUK

$ cat file.txt | base64 -d
one
two
three
$
```

Alternatively, using the [highest voted bash for-line-in-file pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1521470/1041364):

```
$ cat file.txt | while read line ; do
    echo "$line" | base64 -d ; 
done
```

Will result in the same:

```
one
two
three
```

Comment: `while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line" | base64 -d; done <file.txt` is considered [better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable)

Comment: `cat file | while read` is 2 anti-patterns - 1) UUOC and 2) pipe to a read loop. See https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001. You're also missing the `IFS=` and `-r` that should be present by default and only removed if you have a very specific reason to do so.