# Is there any way that I can add all the properties to the $GITHUB_ENV

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api, building-github-actions, github-actions-runners

Currently I have a properties file(test.properties) it has all the key pair values, Is there any way that i can add these values to $GITHUB_ENV ??

test.properties ->

- username1=user1
- username2=user2

I haven't added anything in the workflow yet just want to echo all the properties from the proeperties file..

Comment: I've used [this action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/read-properties) for something similar. It's not exactly setting the GITHUB_ENV, but creating an output for each property informed. That may be a useful workaround for now.

Comment: @GuiFalourd it needs docker right??

Comment: This action needs an ubuntu runner (with Docker installed), as it uses a Dockerfile to run the implementation. The proper Github runner for ubuntu (free) will do the trick.

Comment: @GuiFalourd  Thank you but I am looking for something with no docker dependency, and I am using self-hosted runners

Comment: No problem. I recommend to add this point to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

A naïve approach would be iterating over the content of your `.properties` file line-by-line and setting them as environment variables:

```
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - shell: bash
    run: |
      while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
      do
        echo "$line" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      done < test.properties
  - run: echo ${{ env.username1 }}
  - run: echo ${{ env.username2 }}
```

*The bash line that reads the file line-by-line is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10929511/5078746).*

Please note that this example will only work if you have a `.properties` file with no comments and contains only `key=value` pairs