# Script is not loading the next line while reading

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

My script is working but it's not reading the next line of the file .it is giving output for only one user not providing for next user from the users.txt file

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read the file containing the list of users to check
input_file="users.txt"

# Create empty files to hold the output
found_file="users_found.txt"
not_found_file="users_not_found.txt"
echo "" > $found_file
echo "" > $not_found_file

# Loop through each user in the input file
while read user; do
# Try to run the ldapsearch command for the user
if ssh -n ldaptest /opt/ldap/ldapsearch --user $user >/dev/null 2>&1; then
# User was found in LDAP, so append to the found file
echo "$user" >> $found_file
 else
  # User was not found in LDAP, so append to the not found file
 echo "$user" >> $not_found_file
 fi
 done < $input_file
```

The above script will check user is available in ldap or not.if user is available in ldap then it sends its output to found_file else it will send user to not_found_file here it's not reading input on second line.

```
cat -vet users.txt
Testuser1      $
Testuser1         $
Testuser3    $
Testuser4    $
```

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable/10929511#10929511)

Comment: There might be carriage returns on the file or [ssh is eating STDIN](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089) ...

Comment: I have tried with while read -r but still I'm getting same output

Comment: Asking the obvious question: what does `users.txt` look like? Please add the output of `cat -vet users.txt` to your question.

Comment: Shared the o/p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue while using for loop or while loop with ssh. After an execution ssh breaks the loop. Use below logic to get rid of this issue.

```
cat users.txt | while read user; do
   <Your ssh command>
done
```

Comment: _After an execution ssh breaks the loop_ .... Why?

Comment: The problem is that ssh reads from standard input, therefore it eats all your remaining lines.

Comment: Isn't this only if I'm using `-T` (Disable pseudo-terminal allocation) or `-W` (port forwarding)?

Comment: It's not working I'm getting same output

Comment: Do not use -n with your ssh command, its prevent ssh to reading from stdin.

Comment: I have tried without -n as  well I'm getting same output.

Comment: Can you provide your new code here ?

Comment: found_file="users_found.txt"
    not_found_file="users_not_found.txt"
    echo "" > $found_file
    echo "" > $not_found_file


    cat users.txt | while read user; do

    if ssh ldaptest /opt/ldap/ldapsearch --user $user >/dev/null 2>&1; then
echo "$user" >> $found_file
 else
  # User was not found in LDAP, so append to the not found file
 echo "$user" >> $not_found_file
 fi
 done

Comment: found_file="users_found.txt" not_found_file="users_not_found.txt"
echo "" > $found_file
echo "" > $not_found_file
cat users.txt | while read user; do
ssh ldaptest /opt/ldap/ldapsearch --user $user >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    echo "$user" >> $found_file
else # User was not found in LDAP, so append to the not found file
    echo "$user" >> $not_found_file
 fi
 done

Comment: That worked I have added in script thankyou

Comment: Glad to here that, you are welcome.