# In bash script, how to take a whole line as argument?

Tags: bash

For example, I have a file 'zz'.

```
wire [3:0] dcs_ctrl
```

And I want to print like this.

```
wire [3:0] dcs_ctrl0
wire [3:0] dcs_ctrl1
wire [3:0] dcs_ctrl2
wire [3:0] dcs_ctrl3
```

For this, I want to do the operation for the whole line (like print the whole line 4 times as following).

But when I do

```
for i in `cat zz`; do for j in {0..3}; do echo "$i"; done; done
```

I get:

```
wire
wire
wire
wire
[3:0]
[3:0]
[3:0]
[3:0]
dcs_ctrl
dcs_ctrl
dcs_ctrl
dcs_ctrl
```

So the `for` loop has taken the space-separated words as separate arguments. How can I pass the whole line as an argument to the for loop body?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of ["Read a file line by line assigning the value to a variable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/read-a-file-line-by-line-assigning-the-value-to-a-variable) and ["Looping through the content of a file in Bash"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default seperator in bash is space  , and you can set the default seperator to `\n` with `IFS=$'\n'` when you want do seperate by line.

```
$ cat zz
wire [3:0] dcs_ctrl

$ IFS=$'\n'; for i in `cat zz`; do for j in {0..3}; do echo "$i"; done; done
wire [3:0] dcs_ctrl
wire [3:0] dcs_ctrl
wire [3:0] dcs_ctrl
wire [3:0] dcs_ctrl
```

---

But this is not the prefered way, according to the comment below of  [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson).

You can use the `while loop` instead, as the example in answer of [mandy8055](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77823774/6521116)

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  for j in {0..3}; do
    echo "$line"
  done
done < zz
```

Refer to:

[How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

[Why you don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: Thank you. This is the type of answer I wanted. But why should I set IFS=$'\n', not IFS='\n'? (I tested but only $'\n' works correctly).

Comment: Refer to this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/184863

Comment: Please don't do this, it still has weird problems. For example, if your file has a line consisting of just `*`, it'll be replaced by a list of files in the current directory. Because unquoted expansions like this undergo word splitting *and wildcard expansion* (which includes square braces). It's also inefficient. Use a `while read` loop instead.  See [BashFAQ #1: "How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and ["Why you don't read lines with `for`"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: Otherwise `set -f` can be used to avoid file expansion issue. Another issue if the file is big `read` is slow, for this simple case `sed -e 'p;p;p'` or or `perl -pe 'print;print;print'` can also be used.

Comment: Also for `read line` `IFS=$'\n'` is needed to avoid space trimming and `read -r` option to avoid issues with backslashes

Answer (score 4):

Simply read the the file `zz` line by line and store each line in the **`line` variable** and iterate over it. Something like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
  for j in {0..3}; do
    echo "$line"
  done
done < zz

# outputs:
# wire [3:0] dcs_ctrl 4 times
```

---

#### Alternative solution(*using awk*)

```bash
awk '{for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) print}' zz
```

*[Demo here](https://onlinegdb.com/5ththuKPQ)*

---

**SIDENOTE(*h/t [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson)*):**

- *[Why you do not read lines with "for" loop?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)*

Comment: This works but I chose LF-DevJourney's answer because it keeps the framework of my question. But a pluse one. Thank you.

Comment: @ChanKim Based on years of bash scripting experience, `for` loop is the wrong tool for this job; `while read` is much better. Actually, the standard version is `while IFS= read -r` -- the `IFS=` temporarily disables whitespace recognition so it won't be trimmed from the beginning or end of lines, and `-r` tells `read` not to try to parse backslashes in the input.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

for j in {0..3}; do
awk '{print $0}' zz
done

Comment: Technically correct, but you are reading the file unnecessarily 4 times, so I don't think this should  be a recommended approach.

Comment: The code has a syntax error (missing semicolon before the `done`).  When that error is corrected the code runs but does the wrong thing: it repeats the whole file 4 times instead of repeating each line 4 times.  Also note that `awk '{print $0}'` can be replaced with `cat`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).